# windows option missing after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu. I have a HP Envy laptop with pre-installed windows 8.1 I have created a Ubuntu bootable usb drive and installed Ubuntu successfully. After installation, I am not able to load windows, everytime system is directly loading Ubuntu.

More information: Windows OS is available on C: driver, D: drive is having recovery provided by HP. I created a new drive E: by shrinking C: drive and installed ubuntu on E: drive.

I have gone through existing threads around this issue in Ubuntu community but could not find anything helpful. I have installed boot-repair software and captured my boot information [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9615717/)

Any help/information/education would be much appreciated!

Please suggest if any further information is required to better illustrate this issue.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Install Grub bootloader ( If you haven't installed already) open a terminal and run:

> sudo update-grub

Answer (score 1):

You can install Grub Customiser:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Example of the interface: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bmmp.png

Comment: I run these commands in terminal, I got the following message. gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpfrnrsgs4/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpfrnrsgs4/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 3F055C03 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpfrnrsgs4/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 3F055C03: public key "Launchpad PPA for Daniel Richter" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK                                                               But I do not find 'grub-customizer' software in search.

Comment: Install success. But I dont see 'windows' option in list configuration tab of grub-customizer. I see below options

Comment: <<Here is my complete comment>> Install success. But I dont see 'windows' option in list configuration tab of grub-customizer. I see below options (1)Ubuntu (2)EFI/refind/MokManager.efit (3)EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi (4)EFI/refind/drivers_x64/ext4_x64.efi(5)System setup. Does it mean I completely erased windows? Is there a way to know if windows is existing on hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

Install `os-prober`

Run it.

`sudo os-prober`

Then update grub

`sudo update-grub`

Comment: worked on Arch! :)

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If that doesn't work, then you can try boot-repair tool to fix that as well. Its easy and effective.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Use it to fix your installation. For more details here: [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

From :

[How to fix blank screen with mouse pointer on Ubuntu install reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554399/how-to-fix-blank-screen-with-mouse-pointer-on-ubuntu-install-reboot)

This fixed my **BOTH** problems of

1. mouse not showing in ubuntu and
2. windows option  gone

some times your desktop may not load due to problem with `lightdm`.

press CTRL + ALT + F4 then login using your username and password

```
 sudo apt-get purge lightdm
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install lightdm
    dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Now  type `sudo shutdown -r now` to restart.