# I messed up my Windows 8.1 installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I had 2 hard drives originally installed 1 with a windows 8.1 Pro N install and the other to store stuff on it.
 I acquired a 3rd hard drive and installed Linux on it. It successfully booted, And I made it 1st boot priority in BIOS. When I wanted to go to my windows install, I made it 1st boot priority and it gave me a screen that said "Use the Up Down keys to select choice" and it gave me a list of options in the order like this

`Ubuntu`,
`Advanced Options for Ubuntu`,
I don't remember this one,
`Windows 8.1`

But when it comes to this screen, my keyboard doesn't work. Then I tried unplugging the hard drive and make it boot of the win hard drive. When it does, my board says `Verifying DMI Pool Data` like it always does. but then it says could not find a bunch of letters and numbers, I'm assuming its the serial or address of the hard-drive and it says below it `Entering Rescue Mode` then underneath it `Grub>` and hangs. any type of help will do. 
 Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows option missing after installing ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/565174/windows-option-missing-after-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: Specs' if it matters
AMD Phenon II x3 720 3.3 Ghz
4.0 GB DDR2 Ram
GTX 750 ti

Comment: @earthmeLon I Did that and now it wont run my ubuntu and it wont run my windows.

Comment: Did what exactly? There are many different answers there...