# Can't get to login screen (Ubuntu server 14.04 with Lubuntu)

Tags: 14.04, boot, lubuntu, login

I'm trying to get up a gui on my Ubuntu server (14.04), but failing despite trying some different things.

What I'm seeing: Machine boots to blank screen with a cursor (arrow) in the middle. I can move the cursor.

What I did after clean install:

```
# install, boot to command line, log in
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
dist-upgrade
sudo reboot # so os can boot with new kernel
sudo nano /etc/default/grub 
# set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-desktop
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
## put the following
# [SeatDefaults]
# greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
# user-session=Lubuntu
sudo reboot
```

At this point the login screen should appear, but it doesn't. From here, I tried to do this, as suggested here [How to fix blank screen with mouse pointer on Ubuntu install reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554399)

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Now upon reboot, there is a slight change: there seems to be something 'underneath' the blank screen, since at some areas of the screen the cursor symbol changes form arrow to a text cursor (looks like a T with another line underneath)

I also tried to reinstall lubuntu, but with no effect.

How can I get up my login screen?

Answer (score 0):

open Terminal using ctrl+alt+F3 and login
type ls and you'll see a file in your home called .Xauthority
replace it using this command

> mv .Xauthority .Xauthority1
>   then reboot
>   tell us if it works

Comment: it seems to have no effect

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared when I reinstalled the OS on a 3.0 USB stick (32GB) instead of on the initial 2.0 stick (16GB). I followed the exact same routine as before, only difference was the USB. I still don't know what exactly the problem was, just that this solved it for some reason.