# How to fix the screen loading issue in Ubuntu

Tags: boot

After updating the Ubuntu version in my laptop and it said to restart. After restating the Ubuntu, I am getting this black blank screen with a blinking underscore on my laptop.

[image]

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? What version of Ubuntu to what version? Can you boot to grub menu. If only Ubuntu and If UEFI, its escape key just after vendor's logo on screen and before grub menu would normally appear. And then boot recovery mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix blank screen with mouse pointer on Ubuntu install reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554399/how-to-fix-blank-screen-with-mouse-pointer-on-ubuntu-install-reboot)