# First ubuntu booting takes way too long

Tags: boot

I have decided to install ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my acer e5-571. It had new HDD, completely clean. I have installed it successfully. After first booting the prompt commanded me to remove usb drive and press ENTER. I did it. After that MOK management appeared and I clicked "continue booting" or similar. After that black screen appears with underscore appearing and dissapearing. Please help :c

Edit: I have tried to wipe disc and reinstall again with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1
```

but wiping didnt work it still boots the same way :c

Edit 2: I have tried to wipe it with

```
wipe -q /dev/sda
```

and now it prints "no bootable device" :cccc

Comment: Could you update your question to include which model of Acer you're using? This may help someone provide more specific support as not all Acers are the same 

Comment: Acer often needs UEFI update and if SSD, firmware update to SSD. If mok issues, often related to UEFI Secure Boot. If you have proprietary driver like nVidia, you have to set your own key. Often easier just to turn off UEFI Secure Boot. Most Acer need you to set "trust" on ubuntu entry in UEFI, but Secure Boot has to be on to do that. Newer posts say  update to UEFI works, do not downgrade. Acer E5-573G, supervisor password & trust on ubuntu
http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m?noredirect=1#comment1039248_706912

Comment: I was about to write it. I disabled UEFI secure boot and it worked like a charm. I have decided to do that after I have seen during booting a warning concerning X509 certifacate. Unfortuanately i have another problem beacuse fdisks shows two seperate partitions on my HDD, 465GB each but whole HDD is 500GB so something went wrong. But this is my "backup" laptop so I am not going to try to fix it. Thanks for your help :)

Edit: The two partiotions error is a result of trying deleting the disk and installing it again, it's not tied to questions title

Comment: There might be some help here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/297080/ubuntu-open-to-black-screen-with-blinking-underscore-character-after-release-upg

Comment: Damn i wish i have seen it earlier. Maybe someone will stumble upon your answer in this post.

Comment: @oldfred if you post your comment as question I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acer often needs UEFI update and if SSD, firmware update to SSD.

If mok issues, often related to UEFI Secure Boot. If you have proprietary driver like nVidia, you have to set your own key to authorize the proprietary driver.
Often easier just to turn off UEFI Secure Boot.

Acer need you to set "trust" on ubuntu entry in UEFI, but Secure Boot has to be on to do that. Newer Acer seem to also need <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to open settings for AHCI or other.

Issues are often common by brand as essentially same UEFI used. More difference between Intel & AMD based systems, but still by brand.

Newer posts say update to UEFI works, do not downgrade as per this answer.
Acer E5-573G, supervisor password & trust on ubuntu

[Getting a black screen when installing or Live booting Ubuntu (any version) in my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m)

Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702

Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35

[Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot)