# Help regarding installation on acer aspire e5-573 - after finishing installing from USB, boot option does not show up

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, 21.04

So I have attempted to install Ubuntuvon my Acer aspire e5-573. This laptop I could consider it a fossil, so I thought about making it run easier by replacing windows with ubuntu. Before this it was running in legacy boot mode, so I swapped it to UEFI with secure boot disabled and had to restart like twice for the USB to show up by itself. I have deleted the windows on it and replaced it with ubuntu, but the thing is that it does not show up in the boot menu at all. After the USB installation I removed the USB and pressed enter, laptop proceeded to restart and then no bootable drive found. I restarted several times with no success and I even re- installed ubuntu again and it still did not show up. Considering that now my only option is booting from the USB, how would I make it appear in the boot menu?
The USB was setup with FAT32.

Comment: Before anything else you should check UEFI > Boot menu.

Comment: acer e5-571 new HDD
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312112/first-ubuntu-booting-takes-way-too-long/1312725#1312725  One post with e5 said they had to downgrade UEFI, but newer ones said the update latest worked. Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot Note that Ubuntu is also a larger system. Kubuntu is midweight &  https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie