# When i installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows for Dual Boot all of this happened and i didn't find any solution online to my problem

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows, acer

Hello everyone this will be a long story.

First I installed Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC, then I wanted to dual boot it with Ubuntu 22.04. I allocated free space for it then I made a bootable GPT/FAT32 USB stick with this version of Ubuntu for installation. I made /home (ext4) , / (ext4) and a swap area (2GB).

During the installation of Ubuntu 22.04 I didn't find the option saying "Install alongside Windows" I chose the Something Else option and I performed my installation. after the installation it required a restart.

When I restarted it automatically booted windows 10 without even showing the grub menu to choose between both systems. i read online that I should make Ubuntu first in the list of boot menu .. I didn't find the two names of both systems I just found my hard drive to boot with..

I followed another lead online that says I should select a UEFI file as trusted for executing. Mine is Acer E5-575G-532G I couldn't make that option unless (as another lead online says) I set a supervisor password .. but then I didn't find what everyone found; the HDD0 option didn't appear. simply the list was empty .. no disk found at all .. all of this trying to fix the "No Bootable Device Found" issue when booting with UEFI secure boot mode.

Windows 10 is now only booting on Legacy not secured boot mode. I deleted all other partitions from windows 10 but still booting in Legacy mode. I don't know why all this complications when dual booting Ubuntu alongside windows and vise versa. I just want this to happen easily with success and no issues.

I hated windows for permanent lagging and hated Linux for gaming issues and incompatibility. If anyone understood me and have an easy safe solution to this give me instructions with screenshots or even a tutorial video because frankly I'm so tired of trying finding solutions to everything.

If necessary i can leave my Facebook  or anything for direct contacting. I'm desperate to solve this big problem that occurred to me.

Comment: If booting in Legacy mode, I do not think you correctly installed Windows. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. Older instructions, but still they same: https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312112/first-ubuntu-booting-takes-way-too-long/1312725#1312725

Comment: If the machine is UEFI, there's a small boot partition in addition to the OS partition(s). Windows 10 also creates a small recovery partition and another little one that doesn't seem to have anything on it (not sure exactly what it does). The point is: When you "deleted every other partition" I hope you left all four required Windows partitions. IF it's UEFI (as opposed to old-school BIOS). If it's BIOS, then never mind, this comment doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

You messed up when you created partitions for Ubuntu before installation.

In order to get the "Install alongside Windows" option, you must have enough **unallocated free space** for Ubuntu. That means there must not be a partition created in advance. The Ubuntu installer will create a partition for you.

The second requirement to get the guided installation is that the USB installation media has to be booted in the same mode where Windows is already installed. This is typically UEFI so you must boot the USB as UEFI.

Along the same lines, you do **not** need to create a separate home partition nor do you need a swap partition.  Ubuntu will use a swap file in absence of a swap partition. And a home partition is not useful for most people.  This is why the default installation options do not create all of these extra partitions.

I suggest that you delete the Ubuntu partitions you created so that there is unallocated space and start over with the above information in mind.

Comment: i deleted every other partion than windows10 and i tried reinstalling again ubuntu but still no "Install alongside windows" i'll try boot the USB in legacy mode because windows too is booting in legacy mode now .. everytime i switch to uefi secured boot mode it shows "no bootable device"

Comment: besides, i just deleted the partition but it's not unallocated it's just free space how can i make it unallocated ?

Comment: Unallocated= not in a partition

Comment: still waiting for full guided solution ! ... :'(

Comment: Have you followed the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop)? It walks you through every step of the entire installation from start to finish. As long as your system has enough unpartitioned space and you boot the USB correctly, then nothing is different for a dual boot configuration except to choose "Install alongside Windows" instead of "Erase disk and install Ubuntu".  However the tutorial also has a tooltip with a link to more advanced operations setting up dual boot configuration with Windows. Again your biggest mistake was making partitions.

Comment: now i only have green free space and i can't make it black unallocated space.. how can i do that ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by green vs black. You need to either delete partitions or shrink existing ones. If you need help shrinking your Windows partition, you can search/ask on Super User (We can't help with Windows issues). If you are able to delete partitions, you can use the "Disks" application in a live session (Try Ubuntu booting installation media).

Answer (score 0):

JUST AN OPINION FROM A COMMON USER:

Windows will only boot in two configurations: strictly bios or strictly GPT.
A problem that many are running into is that Ubuntu automatically creates a "hybrid mbr GPT" table when installing or editing partitions. This creates endless boot issues on either windows boot manager or grub. You can make a "Super grub2Disk" usb and use that to boot directly into ubuntu and then reinstall grub from there. Also make sure when installing any OS for EFI boot that you are booting your USB install media in UEFI mode.
My suggestion is that you do a fresh install but you don't have to.
You can use gdisk to change your current setup without having to do a clean install. Additionally you will need to edit /etc/default/grub to allow OS PROBING and then update grub. You can google how to do this for ubuntu 22.04. You might also need to disable hibernation and fast boot in windows power settings.

Here's what I recommend:

1. have secure boot disabled in uefi bios settings
2. install ubuntu first (I know crazy, right)
3. install windows
4. boot into ubuntu with Super Grub2Disk
5. re-install grub2 to EFI

Here's why:
Ubuntu will create a 500MB EFI - this will future proof you if you need space for other boot configurations. Windows only makes a 100MB EFI. You can leave room on the disk for windows during linux install and then later windows will use the same EFI that ubuntu created. It might be useful to learn how to use your windows usb and diskpart in case you have to start again. Make necessary settings in ubuntu, then install windows and make necessary settings, then restore grub.
After you get ubuntu installed you need to convert to a true GPT. You can do this with gdisk which comes pre-installed on ubuntu 22.04.

```
sudo gdisk
```

then enter the disk name you want to edit

```
/dev/sda
```

this should give you a readout that says something about a hybrid mbr
If it says mbr protected then your good to install windows if not...

MAKE SURE SDA IS THE CORRECT DISK!! If you need to know which name is given to the disk you want to install on an easy way is to open gparted and check the name there.

then enter expert mode

```
x
```

then to change disk to GPT

```
n
```

and finally to save your changes

```
w
```

Now windows installer will allow use of disk for uefi install

hope you get something out of this. good luck