# After attempting to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 login LightDM is black (blinking cursor), can't access v-terminal or recovery mode

Tags: boot, 18.04, login, lightdm, virtual-console

I attempted to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 to no avail. After some issues I restarted my computer and now the login screen is just black with occasionally a blinking grey cursor in the top left.

I've attempted to do ctrl+alt+f1-8 and I can get a virtual terminal for a second then it disappears to black again.

Ubuntu recovery mode none of the options do anything. The root terminal fails to open with a `error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1`.

I suspect the issue for the black login screen is this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1286728

But I have no way to access a terminal to make changes because of the libcrypto issue.

Does anyone have any advice? Would I be able to access the file system when booting into an ubuntu usb or other?

EDIT: I'm able to access the filesystem with a usb-ubuntu-trial booted into. I have copied over a fresh 18.04 `libcrypto.so.1` from this usb trial ubuntu onto my original partition at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1` and now the root recovery terminal is working, and LightDM login is working. Just trying to fix my apt issues now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot into an ubuntu usb with usb-ubuntu-trial
2. Copy over a fresh 18.04 libcrypto.so.1 from this usb trial ubuntu onto the original partition at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1
3. Now the root recovery terminal is working, and LightDM login is working

From there I continued with the upgrade by doing `apt update`, and `apt upgrade`, following the steps there.