# Blank boot screen: Potential gdm3 package issue

Tags: boot, 20.04, video, gdm

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on an offline machine. Recently the display port video output has stopped working and it just shows a blank screen with a flashing underscore in the top left corner. I can still access the terminal using `Ctrl+Alt+F2`. When I look at the system log I see the following errors :

```
Feb 21 07:38:35 sdrdev2 org.gnome.OnlineAccounts[2227]: /usr/libexec/goa-daemon: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: cairo_font_options_set_variations
Feb 21 08:54:19 sdrdev2 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch) being skipped.
Feb 21 08:54:19 sdrdev2 kernel: [    0.605284] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
Feb 21 08:54:19 sdrdev2 kernel: [    0.606839] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR01._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Feb 21 08:54:19 sdrdev2 kernel: [    0.606919] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Feb 21 08:54:19 sdrdev2 kernel: [    0.606999] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR03._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Feb 21 08:54:19 sdrdev2 kernel: [    0.607071] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR04._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Feb 21 08:54:19 sdrdev2 kernel: [    0.607143] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR05._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Feb 21 08:54:19 sdrdev2 kernel: [    0.607216] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR06._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Feb 21 08:54:19 sdrdev2 kernel: [    0.607291] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR07._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Feb 21 08:54:19 sdrdev2 kernel: [    2.997692] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
Feb 21 08:54:20 sdrdev2 gnome-session[835]: gnome-session-binary[835]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Feb 21 08:54:20 sdrdev2 gnome-session-binary[835]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Feb 21 08:54:20 sdrdev2 org.gnome.OnlineAccounts[878]: /usr/libexec/goa-daemon: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: cairo_font_options_set_variations
Feb 21 08:54:20 sdrdev2 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[948]: #011(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
Feb 21 08:54:21 sdrdev2 gnome-session[957]: libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
```

Which according to [Ubuntu boots to a black screen with blinking a underscore character after release upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297080/ubuntu-boots-to-a-black-screen-with-blinking-a-underscore-character-after-releas) is a `gdm3`-related issue.

I've tried lots of methods such as uncommenting `Wayland Enable=False`, I've also used `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and `sudo service gdm3 restart` but no change.

My next plan of action is to reinstall gdm3 using a USB drive - before I go through the process of collecting all the dependencies does anyone have other suggestions as to how to resolve the lack of video output? (Yes I’ve already eliminated the possibility of a bad monitor or cable)