# Black screen with underscore after ASUS logo while booting Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2, lightdm, login-screen, gdm

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on ASUS Zenbook-N501VW. But when i try boot my system it shows a black screen with underscore (_) sign after ASUS logo. I have tried the solutions mentioned in this AskUbuntu post: [Ubuntu boots to a black screen with blinking a underscore character after release upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297080/ubuntu-boots-to-a-black-screen-with-blinking-a-underscore-character-after-releas). But none of them have worked for me.

As we know that the both "lightdm" and "gdm3" are famous desktop mangers for Ubuntu. It also helps in loading the login screen after the booting up. But as per the above link I come to know that the all versions of Ubuntu later than 18.04 use "gdm3" as login display manager instead of "lightdm". So for this I tried to run the following commands with root level privileges in recovery mod:

```
    sudo apt-get install
    sudo service gdm3 --full-restart
    dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
    sudo reboot
```

Unfortunately, this hasn't resolved the black screen issue, and I'm still unable to load the login screen.

Can someone please suggest other possible solutions or troubleshooting steps I can try to resolve this issue? Thank you.