# Ubuntu stuck in startup after purple login screen and black window with cursor

Tags: boot, dpkg

I tried to update from ubuntu 18 to version 20. During the installation process, it threw some error messages and I had to restart my computer. After this I have not gotten past the purple ubuntu load screen and the black screen with flashing cursor ([similar to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297080/ubuntu-boots-to-a-black-screen-with-blinking-a-underscore-character-after-releas)).

From the black screen, I can access the terminal with ctrl + alt + f3. I can login and see my files etc. I can see that the current version is 20.04. But I cant get past the black-screen.

From similar questions/posts to my problem, I have figured out that there probably is some issue with dpkg and gdm3.

If I try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` i get the error `gmd3 is broken or not fully installed`. I have tried enabling `WaylandEnable=false`, but this does nothing after reboot.

If I try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or similar, I get this error

```
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Error were encounterd while processing:
fontconfig
libpango-1.0-:amd64
gnome-logs
...
...
gnome-power-manager
...
libkf5kiofileweidgets5:amd64
Processing was halted because there were to manny errors.
```

If I run `sudo apt -f install` or similar, I always get the error message `/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Does anyone know how to fix this? My computer is a Dell Latitude 7400.

Comment: Apparently, the upgrade was not completed. Looks like you need to backup personal data and reinstall.

Comment: Ok, that was what I was suspecting. Can I reinstall from the terminal or do I need to install from usb?

Comment: Sometimes you can complete an interrupted upgrade if the terminal (APT and networking) still works. As you can see, this isn't the case. So, unless others suggest a better solution, do reinstal frum usb.