# 13.04 graphics problem

Tags: unity, 13.04, graphics, transparency

All of a sudden, the graphics aren't working on my Ubuntu 13.04 64bit. I ran sudo apt-get upgrade yesterday, and now the launcher and dash transparency don't work. What's odd is that the notifications transparency-blur-thingy does work. Auto-hiding the launcher also gives me weird results. I have some screenshots:

[image]
The launcher is not transparent.
[image]
Neither is dash.
[image]
And that is what the desktop looks like with the launcher on auto-hide.

My hardware is a Gigabyte h61n motherboard with an intel i3 CPU. What's wierd is that System Settings -> Details can't make up it's mind what graphics I have.

the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0102] (rev 09) Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:d000] 00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04) Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:1c3a]
```

Comment: what is the output for "lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga"?

Comment: @TanelMae 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0102] (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:d000]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
 Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:1c3a]

Comment: Where the lines "Kernel driver in use:" and "Kernel modules:" missing or you didn't copy them? Also edit your question by adding more information about your hardware. If it is a laptop, then usually model name is enough. Mos Have you tried "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade"? (update with dependencies) Also run "sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel" to make sure that for some reason driver has not been removed.

Comment: @TanelMae I think I copied everything, but here it is again: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0102] (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:d000]
 Kernel driver in use: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)

Comment: Test whether you have the driver installed as instructed in my previous comment. Let's hope it is just a driver issue.

Comment: I did all that, logged out and in again, and IT WORKS!!! Thanks ;-) Could you put all that in an answer so I can officially accept your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes things get broken or lost during updates.

Try these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This reruns updates command with some extra features. Read about the difference between apt-get upgrade and apt-get dist-upgrade [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade).

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

This reinstalls the driver if it has been removed for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

How is transparency behaving with

compiz-fusion

and

cairo-dock ?

or else wm ?

Comment: what graphics card you have exactly ? concerning nvidia there is actually a suiting package for CUDA optimus.

Comment: I have an intel h61 chip. Everything works, except the launcher and the dash. But, @TanelMae solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I have noticed that the graphics drivers in the Ubuntu versions since 12.04 have been a bit troublesome. Generally when I see issues like this I just recommend reinstalling the graphics driver. I am not sure if you are using and nvidia or ati card, but try reinstalling the driver. This will force a recompilation of the drivers and will hopefully solve the issue. You can do this through instructions like

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current
```

You could do the equivalent thing for the ATI driver as well.

Comment: I have an integrated intel graphics chip. What do I do?

Comment: Here is the link for the [intel drivers](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.1). Just download and install these. Hopefully that will help

Comment: no hybrid graphics chip ? - only intel integrated ?