# The firefox-Browser obviously created hangings, also I quit this application. But now I run Unbuntu, but without any browser ?? How do I get frf bck?

Tags: firefox, browser

Firefox browser caused system freezes, so I uninstalled it, hoping I could install Firefox without failures again. But now I’m running Unbuntu, but without any browser. I can’t find a  way to install another one. How can I reinstall a browser?

Comment: Please mention the version of Ubuntu, and also, mention the exact steps you had taken. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1372918/edit) your question with these information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating or uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox on Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333411/updating-or-uninstalling-and-reinstalling-firefox-on-linux)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you removed firefox, open a terminal, and enter the following command to install Firefox.

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sudo snap install firefox` for a more recent version. Or
just do `sudo apt install firefox` like Archisman suggested. This will get you an older version of firefox.

Comment: `apt` does get the recent Firefox version within a week. The snap version has a lot of stupid issues.