# Reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, reinstalling

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on dual boot windows 7, and I am trying to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 instead of 12.04

I made a bootable pendrive with Ubuntu 14.04 and plugged it in but there is no installing option showing.

How do I proceed from here?

I do not know anything about linux so I need a lot of help.

Thanks in advance.

---

“You have to boot from the USB drive “

I tried to do it.

I plugged in the pendrive with Ubuntu 14.04. Restarted the computer pressing F12, and I got the boot menu.

One of the options here was “removable drive” but it did not have a star in front of it. When I entered this option I get a regular grub page with no option for pendrive. So I booted to Ubuntu and opened the pendrive with Ubuntu. There was a whole bunch of files in there. I just do not know what to do with them

When I installed Ubuntu 12.04  a couple months back, I just plugged the pendrive with Ubuntu and was able to go through the boot menu to acess intallation.

This time it just does not work that way.

Am I missing something here?

Would you give me step-by-step to boot from USB drive?

---

I booted computer as you said. The boot menu gave me those options:

```
  Removable Drive  (there was no + sign in front of it)
+ Hard Drive
+ CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive
+ Network
   Diagnostics (there was no + sign in front of it)

Set up
```

I selected “Removable Drive” and got :

```
GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3.14

Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-15-generic (recovery mode)
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
Windows7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
```

with no “Try Ubuntu” option.

Comment: You have to boot from the USB drive.

Comment: no “Try Ubuntu” option

Comment: On my system a bootable flash drive in a USB port is shown under hard drives not USB drives. Did you open the hard drive entry with the + to see if the flash drive was there?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all of this stuff. Start your Ubuntu 12.04 OS and do the following steps:

Let's start: Open the terminal by whatever way you like it. Now type in the following command:

```
sudo apt-get do-release-update
```

When it finishes, reboot and a shiny new OS will be installed without any of your files, cat pictures, applications and everything uninstalled.
However, note that upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 is very buggy! So you can do it the safe way, which is the third step. If you want to reinstall 12.04 with the exception of it being 14.04 after the reinstall, you can delete the partition of 12.04, install 12.04 again, and again:

```
sudo apt-get do-release-update
```

Here's what i said what it was the third way, which is like the second way:
Remove the Ubuntu 12.04 partition and install 14.04 using whatever way you want.

Comment: -1 `dist-upgrade` is to update all system packages including kernels and drivers. To upgrade to a new release it is `do-release-upgrade`, this is just wrong, read http://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade

Comment: @markkirby Oh oops, i wanted to `do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in the bootable pen drive and restart. Select the option to boot from USB in the boot options (you need to press F2 or F12 or Esc depending on your computer). 
You should be successfully able to boot then. Follow the on-screen instructions to install Ubuntu.