# On Trusty: there are 19 packages shown as 'not to upgrade'

Tags: 14.04

On a clean install of Trusty, there are (shown by sudo apt-get autoremove) as 'not to upgrade'. Why is this, how can I found out what they are (either by Synaptic or CLI) and should I do something about it?

Answer (score 4):

If a package is marked "not to upgrade" it means that there is a more recent version of the package available, but `apt-get upgrade` will not upgrade to it because it would involve removing currently installed packages, or installing new packages.

From `man apt-get`:

> > apt-get upgrade: Packages currently installed with new versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no circumstances are
> >     currently installed packages removed, or packages not already
> >     installed retrieved and installed. New versions of currently installed
> >     packages that cannot be upgraded without changing the install status
> >     of another package will be left at their current version. An update
> >     must be performed first so that apt-get knows that new versions of
> >     packages are available.

You can force an upgrade by running `apt-get dist-upgrade`, which will satisfy dependencies by removing packages and installing new packages.

For more information see [What is "dist-upgrade" and why does it upgrade more than "upgrade"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Without my doing anything else, sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade resulted in an update of a number of packages (mainly samba ones) & sudo apt-get autoremove no longer showing that there any packages to upgrade.