# How do I upgrade PHP version to the latest stable released version?

Tags: apt, upgrade, php

I'm using a system running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit OS.

I'm currently using following PHP version on this machine:

Command used to get the below info at terminal : `php -v`

Details I got are as below :

```
PHP 5.5.19-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2014 19:32:34) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Now I want to upgrade my PHP software to version 5.5.20.

Before asking the question I tried following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Some information appeared. Then I again hit the following command:

```
php -v
```

but still the PHP software didn't update.

How should I do this?

Comment: How did you get PHP 5.5 on 12.04 in the first place? http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/php5 says it only has 5.3.

Comment: @muru:That I don't know but currently I'm using PHP 5.5.19 is what the fact is.

Comment: Well, without knowing that, how can we know how to upgrade? And did you do `sudo apt-get upgrade` after the `update`?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`apt-get update` updates only the package lists. To actually *upgrade* the packages you have to run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/81585/65926).

---

If you ran the above commands but the packages still were not upgraded, probably you didn't add Ondřej Surý's [PHP PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) to your system.

Run the following to add the PPA:

- For PHP 5.5, PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
  ```
- For PHP 5.4 (Deprecated, upgrade at least to PHP 5.5):

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
  ```
- For PHP 5.5 (Deprecated, use `ppa:ondrej/php`):

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
  ```
- For PHP 5.6 (Deprecated, use `ppa:ondrej/php`):

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
  ```

Then update the package lists and perform the upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

For PHP 5.5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.5
```

For PHP 5.6:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

For PHP 7:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

#### Release upgrade

If you want to install the latest PHP (for example `PHP7`) but you want to stick to the release's packages intead of hacking the sources around; and you want to do a full-release upgrade (for example you are in `Ubuntu 14.04` -which does not have php7- and you want to go to `Ubuntu 16.04` -which does- then you can do:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Now you should have the latest PHP version.

Comment: apt-get install php5

Comment: To upgrade your 5.4 version of PHP, replace `ondrej/php5` with `ondrej/php5-oldstable`. To upgrade your 5.6 version of PHP, replace `ondrej/php5` with `ondrej/php5-5.6`.

Comment: As rotaercz said, but was not very clear about it, you may also have to do an `apt-get install php5` after Eric's original add/update/update sequence for php to actually upgrade to the latest version. Eric, you may want to edit your answer to include the last step.

Comment: After installing the `php5-5.6` PPA, I ran `sudo apt-get install php5` but my PHP version still says `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46)`

Comment: @BadHorsie We need more information. Please [ask](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) a new question and include the output of `lsb_release -a` and `apt-cache policy php5`.

Comment: @EricCarvalho Thanks. http://askubuntu.com/questions/701547/cant-upgrade-to-php-5-6

Comment: I followed this for PHP5.5, and `php -v` gives me `PHP 5.5.37-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2 (cli)`, but `phpinfo()` in apache gives me `PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.23`

Comment: seems support for 12.04 has been removed - https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/248#issuecomment-181874972

Comment: I get `sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found`

Comment: @EdwardBlack Try `add-apt-repository`. Or maybe you have to install the package `software-properties-common`.

Comment: @EricCarvalho Does not work, I tried `apt-get install software-properties-common` but I get many lines with `failed to get http://.... 404 Not found`

Comment: I was unable to retrieve these packages. It appears that they have stopped distribution of these packages for any Ubuntu version lower than 16.04, even though 14.04 is still maintained.

Answer (score 12):

For newest updating process use the following command

```
sudo LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Then run the following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This is worked well when installing php 5.5,5.6 and 7.0

If there some errors this command will resolve the errors

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

> ***Update 2020-10-14: For versions upto 7.****

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

Then

```
sudo apt install php7.2
```

Here also you can use this for php ***7.0,7.1,7.3 to 7.4***

After updating process you can use below command to install extensions

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install php-xml
```

or you can use like below

```
sudo apt install php7.2 php-xml
```

> ***Update 2021-01-31: For versions upto 8.****

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

Then

```
sudo apt install -y php8.0 php8.0-cli php8.0-common
```

Answer (score 5):

Run the following to add the PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

By upgrading PHP from version `5.3` to `5.5`, this may upgrade your Apache from version `2.2` to `2.4`. So be careful.

Comment: `sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found`

Comment: @EdwardBlack do `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties`

Comment: I get "paket 'python-software-properties' not found"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade only PHP 5.3 to 5.5 and do not want to upgrade the system, then you need to install apache 2.4 as well.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2 -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
sudo aptitude update
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Beware about some changes in apache 2.4 related to require grant all.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14

Only this line is needed

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

This will trigger the PPA upgrade system