# Upgraded PHP from 5.4 to 5.6 but phpinfo still shows 5.4

Tags: apache2, php

My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server was using PHP 5.4. I then upgraded to PHP 5.6 using this [How do I upgrade PHP version to the latest stable released version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565784/how-do-i-upgrade-php-version-to-the-latest-stable-released-version) instruction. No errors shown during installation process, reboot server.

`php -v` shows

```
PHP 5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli)
```

`phpinfo` shows `5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~precise+1`

`dpkg -l '*php5*'` output:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version                    Description
+++-==========================-==========================-====================================================================
ii  libapache2-mod-php5        5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
un  libapache2-mod-php5.6      <none>                     (no description available)
un  libapache2-mod-php5filter  <none>                     (no description available)
un  libow-php5                 <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5                       5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
un  php5-cgi                   <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5-cli                   5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-curl                  5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus CURL module for php5
ii  php5-fpm                   5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php5-gd                    5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus GD module for php5
un  php5-gpib                  <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5-idn                   <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5-intl                  5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus internationalisation module for php5
un  php5-json                  <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5-mcrypt                5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus MCrypt module for php5
un  php5-mhash                 <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5-mysql                 5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus MySQL module for php5
un  php5-mysqli                <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5-mysqlnd               <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5-pgsql                 5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus PostgreSQL module for php5
ii  php5-readline              5.4.45-4+deprecated+dontus Readline module for php5
un  php5-suhosin               <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5.6                     5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~prec server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
un  php5.6-calendar            <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-cgi                 <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5.6-cli                 5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~prec command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php5.6-common              5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~prec documentation, examples and common module for PHP
un  php5.6-ctype               <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-exif                <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-fileinfo            <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5.6-fpm                 5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~prec server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
un  php5.6-ftp                 <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-gettext             <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-iconv               <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5.6-json                5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~prec JSON module for PHP
ii  php5.6-opcache             5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~prec Zend OpCache module for PHP
un  php5.6-pdo                 <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-phar                <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-posix               <none>                     (no description available)
ii  php5.6-readline            5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~prec readline module for PHP
un  php5.6-shmop               <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-sockets             <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-sysvmsg             <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-sysvsem             <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-sysvshm             <none>                     (no description available)
un  php5.6-tokenizer           <none>                     (no description available)
```

What should I do to make apache2 uses correct PHP version I wanted which is 5.6?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the `dpkg -l` output shows, your Apache PHP module (package `libapache2-mod-php5`) is at version 5.4. You should install the package `libapache2-mod-php5.6`, which will install version 5.6. It might be necessary to first remove `libapache2-mod-php5`. (You probably also want to remove all the other `php5-*` packages, which belong to PHP 5.4, but this is not required.)