# Apache 500 after Upgrade to PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, apache2, php

I recently upgrade my PHP 5.5 installation to version 5.6. The upgrade completed successfully (I assume) as the php version returned when viewed via `php -v` is:

```
5.6.26
```

However, when I try to spin up my page I get the following error in chrome:

> The **examplesite.com** page isn’t working
>
> **examplesite.com** is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

I checked the Apache error logs and found this:

> [Tue Oct 04 07:39:58.570181 2016] [:notice] [pid 16890] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 16890)
>
> [Tue Oct 04 07:39:58.570420 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1187] AH00163: Apache/2.4.20 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Tue Oct 04 07:39:58.570434 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1187] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>
> [Tue Oct 04 13:54:46.291520 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1187] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

These same lines appear 3 or 4 times, though not when I access a page, only when I run the following commands:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I upgraded my PHP installation by following the advice from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565784/how-do-i-upgrade-php-version-to-the-latest-stable-released-version).

I ran the following commands to complete the upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Any advice on what I did wrong?

Comment: is apache running or not? can you post the ouput for this 2 commands : `sudo apache2ctl -V ` and `sudo service apache status`

Comment: @bistoco Sorry, I feel really stupid now. It turns out it wasn't an apache problem at all. During the PHP 5.6 upgrade, many of my php extensions were removed including the `mbstring` extension which is required in my app. Reinstalling the missing extensions fixed the problems.

Comment: don't worry, the same happened to me, i should have noticed the 500 error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was unexpected. It turns out my problem was not related to the above *Apache* logs at all. When I upgraded the PHP version from 5.5 to 5.6, many of my extensions including `mysql`, `curl` and `mbstring` were removed. Reinstalling these extensions using the appropriate commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5.6-curl
```

combined with the *Apache* commands:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 restart
```

resolved all of my problems.

Apologies for the ignorance on this. I should have checked the extensions first.