# Error composer update in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I have update composer in Ubuntu but I have this error:

[image]

I install curl with apt/get install Ubuntu and I have this version of curl

> curl 7.47.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3

and I install multiple extensions of php5.6 : php5.6-common,php5.6-zip,php5.6-mbstring.php5.6-curl and more extensions php5.6 but I have error

How to resolve the error please? Thank you.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt -f install`?

Comment: after run apt -f install I have this message : Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxmlrpc-epi0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: help me please ...

Comment: curl 7.47.0 is not compatible with php5.6, so you have two-alternatives: [Install curl5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800606/how-to-install-php-curl-in-ubuntu-16-04) or upgrade [php to php7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565784/how-do-i-upgrade-php-version-to-the-latest-stable-released-version). You have to avail which one will brings minor impact to your framework.

Comment: I remove curl 7.47.0 and i install apt-get install php5.6-curl but I also error :(

Comment: Help me please ...

Comment: What's your ubuntu version? Please edit your question and post output this command:  `php --version`. Did you follow curl5.6 page install I linked above? I followed it and worked for me.

Comment: My version ubuntu 16.10 and i install php5.6-curl but also error

Comment: OK. So you have php5.6,  php5.6-common,php5.6-zip,php5.6-mbstring, all these are installed, minus php5.6-curl. Is it? Did you do these commands: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
`sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`. What error messages did you get? You must feed your question with these info. It's hard to see what you are doing, you even answered if you even have php5.6 installed nor what php do you have.