# The difference between the different APT upgrade commands

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, updates

I have seen and used all of these commands to upgrade packages on my system, but why are there different commands for this? Do they all not do the same thing? And if not, then in which situations would it be better to use a specific one of them?

These are the commands I mean:

- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
- `sudo apt full-upgrade`

I have already looked at this, but it does not answer my question about the command `sudo apt full-upgrade`: [What is "dist-upgrade" and why does it upgrade more than "upgrade"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585)

Comment: see also - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/apt-get.8.html all the options are clearly explained on the man page

Comment: @bodhi.zazen see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/apt.8.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, they don't the the same thing.

`sudo apt-get update` updates the list of packages. Do this *before* you use `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` because if the list isn't updated, they won't do anything.

`sudo apt-get upgrade` upgrades your packages but doesn't remove or install any other packages.

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` upgrades your packages and installs or removes other packages to resolve dependencies so all packages are up-to-date.

`sudo apt full-upgrade` performs the function of `upgrade` but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole.

Comment: What about `sudo apt full-upgrade` then?

Comment: @Toroidal same as `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, upgrade the linux to a newer release?

Comment: No, that's what `sudo do-release-upgrade` does. But you should definitely run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` first.