# I can't update my system ubuntu 14.4

Tags: updates

```
minna@minna-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get updates
[sudo] password for minna: 
E: Invalid operation updates
minna@minna-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get install updates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package updates
minna@minna-System-Product-Name:~$
```

this is the message i got when I tried in terminal. earlier I updated from soft ware updator I get the message the upgrade needs a total of 77.7MB free space on disk'/boot' `Please free atleast an additional 4.970k of disk space on'/boot'.Empty your thrash and remove temporary packages of former installations using sudo apt-get clean.`this was the message .when I do that in terminal it shows that no such commands found.Then what can I do to update my system?

Answer (score 2):

The correct command for updating your system's local list of packages is:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And to properly upgrade all packages on the system that need it ([The difference between the different APT upgrade commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605719/the-difference-between-the-different-apt-upgrade-commands)):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(And not `...updates`.)

The next thing is this:

```
sudo apt-get install updates
```

This means that you want to install a program called `updates` which does not exist.

And the last thing: If you don't have enough free space available for an update, you have to follow the instruction and delete at least 5MB of your data on your boot partition.