# apt full-upgrade versus apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: command-line, apt

In accordance with man pages:

- `apt` has parameter `full-upgrade`
- `apt-get` has parameter `dist-upgrade`.

Are both the same command?

btw: which is officially the recommended command in Ubuntu 16.04? `apt` or `apt-get`?

Comment: The officially recommended command for Ubuntu 16.04 and beyond is `apt` instead of `apt-get`. Compare https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/package-management.html with https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/package-management.html .

Answer (score 77):

`apt full-upgrade` performs the same function as `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

#### [`man apt`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/apt.8.html)

> **full-upgrade** (apt-get(8)) performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole.

#### [`man apt-get`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)

> **dist-upgrade** in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade command may therefore remove some packages. The
> /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding the general settings for
> individual packages.

Comment: Why create confusion with a new name that does the same thing?  You can do either `apt dist-upgrade` (I just tried it) or you can do `apt full-upgrade` and you are saying they do the same thing.

Comment: "full-upgrade" is about removing installed packages when necessary, while "dist-upgrade" is about "intelligently handling changing dependencies with new versions of packages", how is it the same function ?

Comment: The man page of apt-get also mentions that "The dist-upgrade command may therefore remove some packages.", so I suppose this man page is just more precise than the man page of apt. Also see: http://askubuntu.com/a/605721/647789

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/

Comment: It's the same function. It's just an alias in `apt` for the `apt-get` command. https://sources.debian.org/src/apt/1.6.1/cmdline/apt.cc/?hl=74#L74 (the actual macro invoked seems to be missing from the repo though).

Comment: @Zboson The reason for the new name is that the "dist-upgrade" name was itself extremely confusing for many users: while it was named that because it was something you needed when upgrading between distribution releases, it sounded too much as though it was *only* for use in that circumstance, whereas in fact it's much more broadly applicable.

Comment: **Careful!!** They are NOT the same command. I just ran `sudo apt-get full-upgrade` and it automatically removed some crucial packages in order to upgrade some trivial ones. I'm now spending the last hour of my work day fixing the mess. I routinely run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and it performs the correct upgrades. This is the preferable command.

Comment: @kael There must have been something else at play because they execute the same code. See my answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1316448/981291

Comment: @bernie: It is not clear from your answer that they execute the same code. See my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 77):

Yes they are the same command. This part of apt's [cmdline/apt.cc](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/cmdline/apt.cc#L74) proves it:

```cpp
static std::vector<aptDispatchWithHelp> GetCommands()            /*{{{*/
{
   return {
      // [snip]
    
      // system wide stuff
      {"update", &DoUpdate, _("update list of available packages")},
      {"upgrade", &DoUpgrade, _("upgrade the system by installing/upgrading packages")},
      {"full-upgrade", &DoDistUpgrade, _("upgrade the system by removing/installing/upgrading packages")},
    
      // misc
      {"edit-sources", &EditSources, _("edit the source information file")},
      {"moo", &DoMoo, nullptr},
    
      // for compat with muscle memory
      {"dist-upgrade", &DoDistUpgrade, nullptr},
    
      // [snip]
   };
}
```

And for completeness, [cmdline/apt-get.cc](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/cmdline/apt-get.cc#L415):

```cpp
static std::vector<aptDispatchWithHelp> GetCommands()           /*{{{*/
{
   return {
      // [snip]
      {"dist-upgrade", &DoDistUpgrade, _("Distribution upgrade, see apt-get(8)")},
      {"full-upgrade", &DoDistUpgrade, nullptr},
      // [snip]
   };
}
```

For both `apt` and `apt-get`, `full-upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` both refer to the same `DoDistUpgrade` function and therefore do the same thing except that `apt` has a different default option here:

> After packages are successfully installed by apt(8), the corresponding .deb package files will be removed from the /var/cache/apt/archives cache directory

`APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages` can control this behavior for `apt-get`.

### Bonus investigation

@Lii raised a good point that `DoDistUpgrade` could act differently based on the binary used (i.e. `argv[0]`). The code is much less straightforward than I expected because there are a number of layers to consider and global variables, but let's have a look.

The [`ParseCommandLine` function](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/apt-private/private-cmndline.cc#L487) is used for both binaries. The function does these steps where the command line could have an impact:

1. [`InitLocale(Binary)`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/apt-private/private-main.cc#L19): same code for all cases.
2. [`pkgInitConfig(**Cnf)`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/apt-pkg/init.cc#L127): all cases use the `extern Configuration *_config` global variable.
3. [`BinarySpecificConfiguration(argv[0])`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/apt-private/private-cmndline.cc#L471): now this is interesting. `apt` has these meaningful default options that are different to `apt-get`:

   1. `APT::Get::Upgrade-Allow-New = true`. That's the `--with-new-pkgs` option to `apt-get` enabled by default. This is documented in `apt`'s manual, but the impact here is only on the `upgrade` command.
   2. `APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages = false`. **This is an actual difference between `apt` and `apt-get`** and is explained in the [NEWS file](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/debian/NEWS#L101):

   > [ Automatic removal of debs after install ]
   > After packages are successfully installed by apt(8),
   > the corresponding .deb package files will be
   > removed from the /var/cache/apt/archives cache directory.
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > Please note that the behavior of apt-get is unchanged. The
   > downloaded debs will be kept in the cache directory after they
   > are installed.
4. [`BinaryCommandSpecificConfiguration(argv[0], CmdCalled)`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/apt-private/private-cmndline.cc#L471) both binaries do the same thing for all these commands: `"upgrade", "dist-upgrade", "full-upgrade"`.
5. `_config->MoveSubTree(conf.c_str(), nullptr)` applies options prefixed by `Binary::apt::apt` or `Binary::apt::apt-get` depending on the binary used.

Other irrelevant steps omitted.

The [`DispatchCommandLine`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/apt-private/private-cmndline.cc#L555) function then ends up calling the `DoDistUpgrade` handler.

Later in the callstack there's this interesting part in `DoCacheManipulationFromCommandLine()` line [681](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/apt-private/private-install.cc#L681):

```
     bool const distUpgradeMode = strcmp(CmdL.FileList[0], "dist-upgrade") == 0 || strcmp(CmdL.FileList[0], "full-upgrade") == 0;

     bool resolver_fail = false;
     if (distUpgradeMode == true || UpgradeMode != APT::Upgrade::ALLOW_EVERYTHING)
        resolver_fail = APT::Upgrade::Upgrade(Cache, UpgradeMode, &Progress);
```

Here again, both binaries with either command perform the same steps.

Perhaps I missed something, but that's where I'm stopping this investigation.

Comment: Judging only from the given source code snippets it is not 100 % clear that they do the same thing. They could for example do mostly the same thing, but also contain if-statements that do different things depending on arguments to the function.

Comment: That's true, but if you look further in `private-cmndline.cc` (https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.6.12/apt-private/private-cmndline.cc#L487), you can inspect how the `std::vector<aptDispatchWithHelp>` instance returned by `GetCommands()` is used and you'll see that the `Handler` function of `aptDispatchWithHelp` is called directly and can't know what it's called from (unless it checks the stack perhaps or uses some other unexpected operation).

Comment: But it seems like `DoDistUpgrade` takes as an argument the list of command line argument? It could check the contents of the command line arguments and figure out if `dist-upgrade` or `full-upgrade` was used. It probably doesn't and I think your conclusion is correct, but it is a bit tricky to be 100 % sure...

Comment: I investigated further and found a difference between `apt` and `apt-get`. I updated my answer to capture this.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Code is tricky...

Answer (score 6):

Use apt as a first choice, but if you're scripting use apt-get.  Apt-get has more stable output (meaning that the output format is left alone as much as possible so as not to break scripts which parse that output automatically).  Apt-get also has some low-level commands not available in apt.

The manual pages for apt and apt-get describe full-upgrade and dist-upgrade a little differently, but they are probably the same command (apt accepts dist-upgrade as an alias of full-upgrade).  This serves as a good example of apt-gets stability.  In apt, the name was changed to be more user friendly, while in apt-get the name remains unchanged so as not to break compatibility with old scripts.

Answer (score 2):

apt and apt-get are two different commands. `apt` is the newer command and should be used as default. You should change to using apt over apt-get as apt is better.

Comment: Why/how is it better?

Comment: From `apt` man page: `The apt(8) commandline is designed as an end-user tool and it may change behavior between versions. While it tries not to break backward compatibility this is not guaranteed either if a change seems beneficial for interactive use.`

Comment: I disagree, on should use apt if one uses it directly from the command line. But use apt-get in scripts. This because the latter has a stable command line interface, but the former might change as mentioned by Lokesh. Apt is not better it is just meant to be more user friendly

Answer (score 1):

Difference is output:

**apt

- full-upgrade

**

```
root@eesti-ThinkPad-T420:/home/eesti/apollo11# apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  shim
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 uuendatud, 0 värskelt paigaldatud, 0 eemaldada ja 0 uuendamata.
```

**apt-get

- dist-upgrade

**

```
root@eesti-ThinkPad-T420:/home/eesti/apollo11# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  shim
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.

*The following packages could receive security updates with UA Infra: ESM service enabled:
  libpam0g libdjvulibre-text bluez libwebp5 libdns-export162 libqpdf21 gstreamer1.0-alsa libisccfg140 intel-microcode libnss3-tools linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev php7.0-cli vim-common libx11-xcb-dev libnss3-nssdb libcurl3 python-avahi libxml2-utils libgrilo-0.2-1 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps libpam-modules openssl ruby2.3 bluez-cups imagemagick ntfs-3g git-man libsystemd0 linux-image-generic libgd3 libavahi-glib1 nginx-core libicu55 binutils libmagickwand-6.q16-2 squashfs-tools bind9-host php7.0-opcache linux-signed-image-generic libavahi-common-data dnsutils libavahi-common3 libpython3.5 python3.5 php7.0-common git openssh-sftp-server python3.5-minimal libisc160 udev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base libpam-runtime isc-dhcp-common python3.5-dev apache2-data libx11-6 linux-signed-generic nginx-common libudev1 libwebpdemux1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libaspell15 libapr1 apport imagemagick-6.q16 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra php7.0-json libisc-export160 libudev-dev libruby2.3 libcaca0 php7.0-readline python3-apport avahi-daemon systemd-sysv libcurl4-openssl-dev libavahi-core7 libgcrypt20 liblwres141 vim-runtime liblz4-1 vim libpam-systemd libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 distro-info-data libsndfile1 avahi-dnsconfd gstreamer1.0-x systemd libpython3.5-dev gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 libssl-dev libssl-doc libwebpmux1 mysql-common libpam-modules-bin openssh-server libx11-data aspell libopenexr22 openssh-client libmagickcore-6.q16-2 python-libxml2 libmysqlclient20 avahi-autoipd libdns162 libx11-dev qpdf libx11-doc bluez-obexd libdjvulibre21 apport-gtk libxml2 libnss3 apache2-bin ca-certificates vim-tiny imagemagick-common libisccc140 avahi-utils libpython3.5-stdlib libbind9-140 libbluetooth3 libexiv2-14 libavahi-compat-libdnssd1 apache2 libpython3.5-minimal libavahi-client3 apache2-utils curl isc-dhcp-client avahi-discover rpcbind linux-generic libapache2-mod-php7.0 python3-problem-report libcurl3-gnutls libx11-xcb1 libssl1.0.0 tzdata docker.io nginx
Learn more about UA Infra: ESM service for Ubuntu 16.04 at https://ubuntu.com/16-04

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

0 uuendatud, 0 värskelt paigaldatud, 0 eemaldada ja 0 uuendamata.
root@eesti-ThinkPad-T420:/home/eesti/apollo11#
```

So as You can See, it is not really "the same"

Answer (score 0):

Apt is the newer version of the command. You should switch to using apt instead of apt-get. It's better and gives a better idea of what the command is doing.

As for `apt full-upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` it's the same command. But again apt is the newer command.

For example when using apt you get a progress bar to tell you how much of the install/update is done.