# Software Updater - Ubuntu 18.04. How to prevent from update anything

Tags: 18.04, updates

I am new to Ubuntu.

I have installed Ubuntu for my parents desktop. They have very basic knowledge about Computer. They use it for Skype Only.

We are using it from last 1 year. 17.10 to 18.04.1
what i observed is, system is popping up some updates to install in some other days. which is difficult for my parents to proceed further.

We are very much satisfied with the 18.04.1 up to date, i have downloaded latest iso from daily builds yesterday.

**Question:**
I want to stick with this software as it is installed, dont want further updates anymore until i visit my parents house in 6months or 1year.

i thought this would help, so i un tick like below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

also i would like to know, which commands in terminal will update the OS, so that i will not run them.
I generally run

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Please let me know the terminal commands which are equivalent to the GUI "Software Updater" so that i will keep away from those commands.

Comment: The steps you have shown are enough to disable auto-updates, and also not running the commands should be good enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed another command that upgrade the system package, is it `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

So to simply put it up, you ran these command to upgrade Ubuntu package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

There is also `apt full-upgrade` that function the same as `apt-get dist-upgrade`, this command only exist on `apt` tool that available from 14.04 onwards.

**Note:** `apt-get update` command does not install new versions of software. It updates the list of packages and their version, this information then used as reference for package dependencies, version, etc.

Comment: please, if it is same as `apt-get dist-upgrade` what is the difference between these two `apt full-upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`? is `apt` tool a GUI?

Comment: `apt` is not GUI, instead it is command line tool that aim to be pleasant and better suited for interactive usage by default compared to more specialized APT tools like `apt-get`. Source [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html)

Comment: To answer your second question, please read this thread for more details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/770135/apt-full-upgrade-versus-apt-get-dist-upgrade

Comment: Excellent!! Question is clearly explained in the above link. Thank you.