# How do new package versions find their way to the LTS distribution? (Current example: OpenSSL)

Tags: 18.04, package-management, upgrade, updates, openssl

I'm running several Ubuntu 18.04 machines all of which need OpenSSL.

Recently, OpenSSL reported a security problem: https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20200421.txt (CVE-2020-1967).

I did install OpenSSL via the Ubuntu standard packages, no custom package sources here nor did I compile it myself.
So, since this is the case and since I'm using a currently maintained LTS distribution (18.04 as mentioned), I assumed that running `apt update` and `apt upgrade` would be sufficient to get the latest updates and be safe from that vulnerability. But, no. Obviously, it is more complicated.

According to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl there is an OpenSSL package version for Ubuntu which reacts to the aforementioned CVE-2020-1967. However, it still contains 1.1.1f in its version name, whereas the OpenSSL version where the problem is fixed is actually 1.1.1g (according to their advice).
And, more important: That package is only for Focal Fossa (20.04).

So, I thought I take the chance to learn a few things about the internals of Ubuntu and how package version make their way to my computer:

- How come that new packages are only created for newer LTS
  distributions and older ones are left vulnerable?
- How does that process work in general?
- What is the average time between a vulnerability being publicly
  announced and patched packages being available via `apt upgrade`?

Comment: FYI: https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2020/CVE-2020-1967.html and have you `sudo apt full-upgrade`?  (you mention only upgrade). Possibly useful https://askubuntu.com/questions/770135/apt-full-upgrade-versus-apt-get-dist-upgrade

Comment: guiverc's link has `not-affected (code not present)` for 18.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*How come that new packages are only created for newer LTS distributions and older ones are left vulnerable?* is simply **FALSE**, and let's show you how you can determine that for yourself:

First, Let's take a look at the [Ubuntu CVE Tracker](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/).

Key in your CVE number, and you will see:

- The Ubuntu Security Team has already worked this issue.
- Some Ubuntu releases required new packages, others did not.
- The tracker includes the exact package version with the fix.

Second, lots of folks get confused by the Debian/Ubuntu concept of a *snapshot release* model. Under this model, the software in a single release (like 19.10 or 20.04) is NOT incremented by new releases...even most security releases.

- Exceptions: There are a few exceptions, like web browsers, that always get the newest versions on older releases.

HOWEVER, "not incremented" doesn't mean "not fixed". Lots of packages get security patches after release *without* being upgraded to a new version. Let's say that again: **Users** are encouraged to update to newer packages *because most users don't have the skill or patience to patch and recompile a package*. **Distros** like Ubuntu, however, have engineers who do have that skill and patience.

- It's risk management: Newer packages may introduce bugs and haven't been tested with the release, so most packages are patched instead.

Finally, let's build on those two elements and let's take a look at the example of OpenSSL in CVE-2020-1967:

- The Ubuntu Security Team evaluated the vulnerability in six different releases of Ubuntu. The vulnerability was present in one of those releases.
- The upstream release (for users) is version 1.1.1g
- The Security Team patched the vulnerability in 20.04's package 1.1.1f. Since they added a patch instead of merging the new upstream release, they couldn't claim it was 1.1.1f anymore, nor was it 1.1.1g. It was something else, so it's called 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2. Note that the '2' in 'ubuntu2' indicates this is the *third* patch of that package since it came from upstream.
- That labeling scheme for patches isn't accidental - it's carefully designed so you can see at a glance how many patches came from Debian, and how many from Ubuntu. Also, it's still alphanumerically sortable so apt will always correctly identify the highest version to install.
- Finally, after review and testing, the patched package `openssl 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2` was uploaded to 20.04 (Focal) before release. Had the patch occurred after release, it would be in the focal-security repository. This is one reason it's important to keep the -security repo in your sources, and to keep Unattended Upgrades active.