# How to check the version of libssh-dev installed and update to newer version?

Tags: upgrade, ssh, uninstall, versions

I tried to check my libssh-dev version by running the following command:

```
user@client56:~$ dpkg -l | grep libssh
ii  libssh-4:amd64                              0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.5                              amd64        tiny C SSH library (OpenSSL flavor)
ii  libssh-dev                                  0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.5                              amd64        tiny C SSH library. Development files (OpenSSL flavor)
ii  libssh-gcrypt-4:amd64                       0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.5                              amd64        tiny C SSH library (gcrypt flavor)
```

I see "0.6.3-4.3ubuntu0.5" but I'm not sure how to interpret it. I suppose the version is 0.6.3. But what does 4.3 and 0.5 mean?

Also, how do I properly uninstall libssh so that I can manually install the latest version (0.9.4 at the time of writing) from the source tarballs? Or is there are a way to upgrade to the latest version from the version already installed?

EDIT: The number 4.3 refers to the debian version of the package and 0.5 refers to the Ubuntu version of the debian package. More information can be found here: [What is the meaning of the XubuntuY string in Ubuntu package names?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620533/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-xubuntuy-string-in-ubuntu-package-names)

Comment: Run `sudo apt show libssh-4` to see the actual `libssh` version. In my case for ubuntu `20.04` it's `0.9.3`. In Your case You have `0.6.3`. Check here for a versions available for Your ubuntu: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/libssh-4

Comment: Usually you will not be able to upgrade to a 'newer version' unless it's present in the repositories for your Ubuntu version.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software for more details on this.

Comment: I think the main thrust of the question ("*can I use this older package in this older release, or should I use newer packages*" is answered by https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230095/how-do-new-package-versions-find-their-way-to-the-lts-distribution-current-exa/1230104#1230104. 0.9.4 is currently in testing for Ubuntu 20.10 and won't be backported to older releases. However, the Ubuntu Security Team regularly patches those older packages -- they are safe to use. The link explains why.