# When use "sudo apt full-upgrade"? When is mandatory?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

About to accomplish an **update** for the current packages installed - since Ubuntu 18:04 to 20:04 for Desktop and Server environments - I have been always using:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

**Note** just in case - I never used the `apt-get` command, it according with:

- [Difference Between apt and apt-get Explained](https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/)

So far practically, I had none problem and all work as expected.

About do an **upgrade**, I saw practically in all the tutorials being used the same pair mentioned above, and of course it has sense, **but** in *few* places I saw the `sudo apt full-upgrade` command being used.

**Questions**

- When use `sudo apt full-upgrade`?
- When is mandatory?

Comment: It should be noted that `dist-upgrade` is an alias for `full-upgrade` and neither of these will upgrade your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @mchid thanks, but it is not mentioned in the `man apt`, so where is your resource to confirm this pls. Thank You

Comment: There is extensive discussion about the topic [here](https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770135/apt-full-upgrade-versus-apt-get-dist-upgrade)

Comment: Also, [see the source code here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1316448/167115).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`upgrade` is a more cautions way of upgrading than `full-upgrade`.

`upgrade` will never remove one of your currently installed programs. `full-upgrade` may.

If some new package would require newer dependencies that are not compatible with one of your currently installed programs, that upgrade will not be performed with the `upgrade` option. With `full-upgrade`, however, any upgrade will be performed. If that upgrade causes incompatibility with a currently installed package, that package is removed.

I am not sure how likely such scenario is when you use the standard Ubuntu software sources. The Ubuntu packages certainly try to avoid a program suddenly breaking during the life time of your current distribution. Such scenario may be more likely when using third party PPA's.

Comment: @mchid sure about that? My experience is that an `update` also will do kernel updates.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just checked it out and had a kernel update available. Ran `apt upgrade` and compared it to `apt full-upgrade` and the result was the same.

Comment: As far as I know (never done this so far) a `full-upgrade` is needed before running `do-release-upgrade, maybe worth to mention.

Comment: @mook765 yes, you're right, in few tutorials do mention about to use `full-upgrade` before to use `do-release-upgrade` - in others not, just 2 days ago I did do an upgrade process for Ubuntu Server 18:04 to 20:04 **without** `full-upgrade` and all worked fine.