# How can I play videos on Ubuntu? using any player

Tags: 14.04, video, vlc, video-player

I'm newbie with Ubuntu -- I use ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I was trying to play some video using ubuntu video player and it required installing some plugins but this error occurred:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved

This error could be caused by required additional software packages
which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a
conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be
installed at the same time.
```

and here more details:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:    
gstreamer1.0-libav: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but
6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed    
             Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
             Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
             Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
             Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

I tried also to install VLC player and the package dependencies errors occurred again.

and here more details:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but
2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
      Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
      Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4 is to be installed
      Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1 is to be installed
      Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
      Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1 is to be installed
      Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

I tried a lot of solutions published on the internet but they didn't work

how can I solve these errors?

**UPD:** here's the content of the `etc/apt/sources.list.d`

> google-chrome.list google-chrome.list.save
>
> ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.list
>
> ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.list.save
>
> webupd8team-sublime-text-2-trusty.list
>
> webupd8team-sublime-text-2-trusty.list.save

sorry of my bad language, English isn't my native..

Comment: How did you install VLC-player ? (which command line, or which method ?)

Comment: I used ubuntu software center.

Comment: using terminal can you test :`sudo apt-get install vlc` ?

Comment: It said that "I have some broken packages"

Comment: could you please edit your answer by adding the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` (this is the list of the repository then check if this file is update. (for example in france, my local list can be found [here](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/depots_trusty)) **Update** Ok then, make a backup of your source.list and generate new list from [source list generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and just add the lines into the source.list file

Comment: to install vlc run `sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc vlc-nox vlc-data` then `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: what's the output for `uname -r` ?

Comment: @JoKeR, the same problem still exists.

Comment: here's it: 
3.13.0-57-generic

Comment: it means you have got duplicated sources... if you fix it it won't appear anymore to fix it you have to disable those repositories that make conflict as told in a link above... try also `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs`

Comment: are those all the sources you got in */etc/apt/sources* ? you can list it with `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` also main `sudo apt edit-sources`

Comment: yes those are all sources I have. what should I choose after 'sudo apt edit-sources'

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will update your repo cache and then will fix most dependency issues.

---

If this still fails, please try running the below command and then running the above command immediately after.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will update all of your software and ensure that you're running on the latest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: !!! I would not run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`!!! Won't that upgrade him from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 15.04 (not LTS!)

Comment: @MichaelButler IIRC, `dist-upgrade` does not change your distribution, but it will solve package conflicts. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade) for more info.

Comment: Seriously, why can't we downvote comments.