# How do I get openssh 6.9 or greater and Apache2.4.12 or greater on to my 15.04 server?

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, 15.04

I am trying to comply with government requirements and need to keep my 15.04 server up to date. Mostly 15.04 has recent packages. Can I upgrade Apache on the command line? I need openssh 6.9 or better, is that also possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this versions you need a PPA or you need to compile the desired version. The latest version in Vivid for this packages is

```
$ apt-cache policy openssh-server
openssh-server:
  Installed: 1:6.7p1-5ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:6.7p1-5ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:6.7p1-5ubuntu1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and

```
$ apt-cache policy apache2
apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.10-9ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.4.10-9ubuntu1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
```

The version 2.4.12 for `apache2` is in Wily, but no version 6.9 for `openssh-sever`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, run the following commands to upgrade those packages to the newest versions available for 15.04:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

that command updates the list of packages available from the ubuntu server

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server apache2
```

that command will upgrade those packages to the newest versions

You may want to upgrade all packages to get all the newest security u updates:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Finally, you may want to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get the newest kernel updates which also include security updates for the kernel to be most secure but **choose wisely when you run this command** as it **may make changes to the system that can have an effect on the way things function** so do not run the `dist-upgrade` command unless you have some extra down time to spare in case you need to fix some stuff. Also, you may need to reboot after a `dist-upgrade` for the changes to take effect.

[What is "dist-upgrade" and why does it upgrade more than "upgrade"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)