# how to configure a desired Kernel version on Grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I want to configure Grub to pick an specific Kernel version until I change it. But how?

Documentation is most welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Install [grub-optimizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) from the software center and start it. It will let you set the kernel to boot and many more settings.

Without grub-optimizer: GRUB can be set to boot from the kernel it booted from successfully the last time you booted. So that would solve your problem with just a setting.

Use an editor to open `/etc/default/grub` and change ...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Save and update grub with ...

```
sudo update-grub
```