# Avoid updating kernel as I need a specific kernel for my processor?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates, xubuntu

I am going to install Xubuntu 12.04 LTS as it has a non-pae kernel that I need to get it to run on my old PC. Is there any way I can update everything other than the kernel once I get it installed?

Comment: Sure you can. But support off 12.04 will end in a couple of months.

Comment: @pilot6, `upgrade` will not upgrade `kernel` but `dist-upgrade` will, am I right?

Comment: You can hold the kernel packages as well to make sure.

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/a/678633/158442, by @Pilot6

Answer (score 0):

In this Q&A ([Blocking kernel updates with dpkg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63293/blocking-kernel-updates-with-dpkg)) the OP was also on Ubuntu 12.04 and had to hold the kernel at a specific version because things break when upgrading.

A short summary of the link:

First check your kernel image name

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

output for the poster:

```
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64              3.2.35-2                           amd64        Linux 3.2 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64                      3.2+46                             amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

then tell dpkg to hold the metapackage (the generic version without any version numbers)

```
echo linux-image-amd64 hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

You can then check this worked `via dpkg -l linux-image-amd64`

Please read the entire question and answer before proceeding.