# Ubuntu 17.04 freezes with 4.10 kernel but working with older one even after fully os update

Tags: boot, kernel

I've updated my *Ubuntu 16.04* to *17.04*.
There are two kernels *4.10* and *4.8*.

Before the update I was working with kernel  normally as it was the default kernel, now after the update, It manages to get into the login session (GUI), but after I type in the password, the whole system freezes and doesn't respond to any key press and I am forced to power off the computer. However, I can boot into *4.8* from GRUB.

I read about fully update the OS from the lower kernel by using

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

but it didn't work for me.
After reading most users faced a driver issue, how could I know the problem for me?

Comment: Switch to some good distro

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal for example...?

Comment: Antergos, Manjaro

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/939417/ubuntu-16-04-freezes-with-4-10-kernel Do you also use.  an Nvidia GPU? @pomsky Feeding is forbidden on this site ;-) As for manjaro https://forum.manjaro.org/t/system-hangs-with-4-10/18642

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal [Yeah, well, you know, that's just, like, your opinion, man.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWdd6_ZxX8c)

Comment: I'm using Radeon|ATI GPU

Comment: and my question is how to know the problem in which driver? @Bruni

Comment: any help or other solutions?

Comment: Maybe `unity` is having some issue, you can try installing `gnome` desktop environment