# diffrence between update and upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

everyone. I am new to ubuntu. I was just wondering what is the diffrence between `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Alsoe see http://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade for the difference between `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Read The Manual type of question ( which you should be checking always always always before doing anything or before asking questions ) .

- update is used to resynchronize the package index files ( find out what's new) , while upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
         currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
         `/etc/apt/sources.list`  (ie install what's new)
- update must always be ran *before* upgrade
- The update lists go into `/var/lib/apt/lists/` folder, and are commonly in *.list files. Upgrade backages are mostly *.deb files stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` ( but manually installed packages go there also )

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

is command to update the repository (software source).

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

is command to upgrade all of your installed software.