# Ubuntu Software Updater selecting problem

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager

It pops up as usual, yet there are some updates that are unselected and i can't select them. I deselect all, and select all, yet again they are still unselected. I did

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

and after a time it popped and yet again they are still there. How can I fix this? Is it just related with my ubuntu or general issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update` only searches your current repositories for any new/updated packages. If you actually want to update the packages, you need to run `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

You didn't provide many details, but I'm going to assume those packages that aren't getting selected have `linux-image-generic` in their names. If you want to upgrade those, the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` command is what you need to run (after `sudo apt-get update` of course).

For more information on what the difference between `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` is, I recommend [taking a look at this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade#99039).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to update from the command line. Open terminal and type the following in order:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

This should fully update all packages on your system.