# How can I do a dist-upgrade without removing a huge amount of packages?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

I was trying to a dist-upgarde on a machine I have (ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) after an apt-get update but it wants to remove to many packages:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED
  account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr account-plugin-google
  account-plugin-twitter activity-log-manager
  activity-log-manager-control-center akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server
  appmenu-qt appmenu-qt5 apport apport-gtk apt-transport-https apt-utils
  apt-xapian-index aptdaemon aptik aptitude apturl-common audacity banshee
  banshee-extension-soundmenu bbswitch-dkms bluez-cups boot-repair boot-sav
  boot-sav-extra brasero brasero-cdrkit brltty browser-plugin-vlc
  build-essential caribou checkbox-gui cheese chromium-browser
  chromium-browser-l10n cinnamon cinnamon-dbg cinnamon-doc
  cinnamon-screensaver click click-apparmor command-not-found compiz
  compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default
  compiz-plugins-extra compizconfig-settings-manager conky-manager cortina
  cups cups-filters cups-ppdc dblatex default-jdk default-jre
  default-jre-headless deja-dup deja-dup-backend-cloudfiles
  deja-dup-backend-gvfs devhelp dh-autoreconf dkms docbook-to-man dockbarx
  dockbarx-applet-appindicator dockbarx-applet-battery-status
  dockbarx-applet-clock dockbarx-applet-hello-world dockbarx-applet-namebar
  dockbarx-applet-volume-control dockbarx-common dockbarx-dockx
  dockbarx-themes-extra easytag enblend enchant enfuse eog filezilla firefox
  flashplugin-installer frei0r-plugins friends friends-facebook
  friends-twitter g++ g++-4.8 gcc gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-multilib gcc-multilib gdisk
  gdm gedit gedit-plugins gimp gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0
  gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-muffin-3.0
  gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0
  gir1.2-webkit2-3.0 gjs gnome-common gnome-contacts gnome-control-center
  gnome-dbg gnome-media gnome-shell gnome-system-monitor gnome-user-guide
  gnome-video-effects gobject-introspection google-musicmanager-beta gparted
  grilo-plugins-0.2-mediascanner grub-customizer gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-clutter gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gtk-doc-tools gtkpod guayadeque handbrake-gtk
  hplip hud hugin hugin-tools ibus-pinyin id3v2 indicator-bluetooth
  indicator-datetime indicator-network indicator-printers jackd jackd2
  jackd2-firewire jade jstest-gtk katepart kde-runtime kdelibs-bin
  kdelibs5-plugins kdepim-runtime kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdoctools kodi
  kodi-bin kubuntu-debug-installer kwalletmanager landscape-client-ui-install
  language-selector-common language-selector-gnome latex-beamer latex-xcolor
  launchy lib32atomic1 lib32gcc-4.8-dev lib32gomp1 lib32itm1 lib32quadmath0
  lib32stdc++6 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth
  libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-qt1 libaccounts-qt5-1 libadplug-2.2.1-0
  libakonadi-calendar4 libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4
  libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadi-notes4 libakonadi-socialutils4
  libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libasound2-plugins:i386 libatkmm-1.6-1
  libatomic1 libattica0.4 libbaloocore4 libbaloofiles4 libbalooxapian4
  libbasicusageenvironment0 libbinio1ldbl libboost-date-time1.54.0
  libboost-filesystem1.54.0 libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libboost-locale1.54.0
  libboost-program-options1.54.0 libboost-python1.54.0 libboost-regex1.54.0
  libboost-serialization1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0
  libbrasero-media3-1 libcairomm-1.0-1 libcapnp-0.4.0 libcdr-0.0-0 libcec3
  libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libcholmod2.1.2 libchromaprint-tools
  libchromaprint0 libcjs-dev libclucene-contribs1 libclucene-core1
  libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-dbg libclutter-1.0-dev libclutter-gst-2.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-dbg libcmis-0.4-4 libcogl-dev
  libcogl-pango-dev libcogl-pango15 libcogl-pango15-dbg libcogl15
  libcogl15-dbg libcolumbus1 libcompizconfig0 libconfig++9 libcontent-hub0
  libcupsppdc1 libcwidget3 libdbus-cpp2 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386
  libdbusmenu-qt5 libdee-qt5-3 libdevhelp-3-2 libdirac-encoder0 libebml4
  libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-dev libenchant1c2a libept1.4.12 libexempi-dev
  libexiv2-12 libfarstream-0.1-0 libfarstream-0.2-2 libffado2 libflac++6
  libgbm-dev libgbm1 libgcc-4.8-dev libgegl-0.2-0 libgexiv2-2 libgflags2
  libgfortran3 libgirepository1.0-dev libgjs0e libgle3 libgles2-mesa-dev
  libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgme0
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgoogle-glog0 libgroupsock1 libgsettings-qt1
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtkglext1 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-3.0-1
  libgtkspell0 libhud-client2 libhunspell-1.3-0 libid3-3.8.3c2a libilmbase6
  libitm1 libjack-jackd2-0 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0
  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-dev libkabc4
  libkactivities-bin libkactivities-models1 libkactivities6 libkalarmcal2
  libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcmutils4
  libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5
  libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkholidays4 libkhtml5
  libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkmbox4
  libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4
  libkolab0 libkolabxml1 libkonq-common libkonq5abi1 libkparts4
  libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4
  libkrosscore4 libksgrd4 libktexteditor4 libkubuntu0 libkunitconversion4
  libkworkspace4abi2 libkxmlrpcclient4 liblapack3 liblucene++0
  libmagickcore5-extra libmailtransport4 libmatroska6 libmediascanner-1.0-1
  libmediascanner-2.0-0 libmicroblog4 libmirclient7 libmirclientplatform-mesa
  libmirplatformgraphics-mesa libmirprotobuf0 libmirserver18 libmlt++3 libmlt6
  libmodemmanagerqt1 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libmspub-0.0-0
  libmuffin-dev libmuffin0 libmutter0c libmythes-1.2-0 libnepomuk4
  libnepomukcleaner4 libnepomukcore4abi1 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4
  libnetworkmanagerqt1 libntrack-qt4-1 libnux-4.0-0 libofa0 libofono-qt1
  libonline-accounts-client1 libopenconnect2 libopencv-calib3d2.4
  libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-features2d2.4
  libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4
  libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-objdetect2.4
  libopencv-photo2.4 libopencv-video2.4 libopenexr6 liborcus-0.6-0 libosmesa6
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libpangomm-1.4-1
  libphonon4 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4abi4
  libplatform1 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-4 libportaudiocpp0 libportsmf0
  libprison0 libprocess-cpp1 libprocesscore4abi1 libprotobuf8 libproxy-tools
  libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libpurple0
  libpyside1.2 libpyzy-1.0-0 libqapt2 libqapt2-runtime libqca2 libqdjango-db0
  libqgsttools-p1 libqjson0 libqmenumodel0 libqmobipocket1 libqt4-dbus
  libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-dev
  libqt4-dev-bin libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-opengl-dev
  libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql
  libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml
  libqt4-xmlpatterns libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5feedback5 libqt5gui5
  libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5
  libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5organizer5
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml-graphicaleffects libqt5qml5
  libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5
  libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin
  libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libqtassistantclient4
  libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui
  libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtwebkit-dev
  libqtwebkit4 libquadmath0 libqwt5-qt4 libqxt-core0 libqxt-gui0 librados2
  librbd1 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport
  libreoffice-presentation-minimizer libreoffice-writer libresid-builder0c2a
  libretro-2048 libretro-4do libretro-beetle-gba libretro-beetle-lynx
  libretro-beetle-ngp libretro-beetle-pce-fast libretro-beetle-pcfx
  libretro-beetle-psx libretro-beetle-sgx libretro-beetle-vb
  libretro-beetle-wswan libretro-bluemsx libretro-bsnes-accuracy
  libretro-bsnes-balanced libretro-bsnes-mercury-accuracy
  libretro-bsnes-mercury-balanced libretro-bsnes-mercury-performance
  libretro-bsnes-performance libretro-catsfc libretro-desmume
  libretro-dinothawr libretro-fba libretro-fba-cps1 libretro-fba-cps2
  libretro-fba-neogeo libretro-fceumm libretro-fmsx libretro-gambatte
  libretro-genesisplusgx libretro-gpsp libretro-gw libretro-handy
  libretro-mame libretro-mednafen-psx libretro-mess libretro-mgba
  libretro-mupen64plus libretro-nestopia libretro-nxengine libretro-picodrive
  libretro-ppsspp libretro-prboom libretro-prosystem libretro-quicknes
  libretro-snes9x libretro-snes9x-next libretro-stella libretro-tgbdual
  libretro-tyrquake libretro-vba-next libretro-vbam libretro-yabause
  librhythmbox-core9 libsbsms10 libsdl-gfx1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
  libsdl1.2-dev libsdl2-2.0-0 libsidplay1 libsidplay2 libsidutils0
  libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libsignon-extension1 libsignon-plugins-common1
  libsignon-qt1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsolid4 libsoprano4 libsoundtouch0 libsp1c2
  libstdc++-4.8-dev libstreamanalyzer0 libsyndication4 libsynfig0
  libsystemsettings1 libtaskmanager4abi5 libtbb2 libtelepathy-farstream3
  libthreadweaver4 libthumbnailer0 libtinyxml2.6.2 libtool libtotem0 libtsan0
  libubuntu-application-api-mirserver1 libubuntu-application-api1
  libubuntu-download-manager-client0 libubuntu-download-manager-common0
  libubuntu-download-manager-priv0 libubuntu-location-service0
  libubuntu-platform-hardware-api1 libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0 libumfpack5.6.2
  libunity-action-qt1 libunity-api0 libunity-core-6.0-9 libunity-mir1
  libunity-scopes1 libunity-webapps0 libunityvoice1 libusermetricsoutput1
  libvigraimpex5 libvirt-bin libvisio-0.0-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvlc5
  libvlccore7 libwayland-egl1-mesa libweather-ion6 libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25
  libwebkit2gtk-3.0-dev libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwpd-0.9-9
  libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxbase3.0-0 libwxgtk-media2.8-0
  libwxgtk2.8-0 libwxgtk3.0-0 libwxsqlite3-2.8-0 libx32atomic1
  libx32gcc-4.8-dev libx32gomp1 libx32itm1 libx32quadmath0 libxapian22
  libxerces-c3.1 libxml++2.6-2 libyelp0 libzmq3 libzmqpp3 lightsoff lightworks
  livewallpaper livewallpaper-config livewallpaper-indicator lshw
  mediascanner2.0 melt menu metacity mpd muffin muffin-dbg muffin-doc
  musescore mythes-en-us nautilus nemo nemo-dbg nepomuk-core-runtime nitrogen
  nvidia-352 nvidia-prime onboard onboard-data oneconf oneconf-common
  openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openshot openshot-doc
  ophcrack p7zip-full pavucontrol pencil pgf phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer
  phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 picard pinentry-qt4 pipelight pipelight-multi
  plasma-containments-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-nm
  plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-widget-folderview
  plasma-widgets-workspace playonlinux polkit-kde-1 powerd
  printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp
  printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-splix prosper psensor python-apt
  python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-commandnotfound
  python-compizconfig python-mlt python-numpy python-oneconf python-opencv
  python-opengl python-pyexiv2 python-pyside.qtcore python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus
  python-software-properties python-vm-builder python-webkit python-wxgtk2.8
  python-xapian python3-apport python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-click python3-commandnotfound
  python3-distupgrade python3-oneconf python3-software-properties python3-uno
  python3-update-manager qapt-batch qcomicbook qdbus qemu-kvm qemu-system-x86
  qemu-utils qjackctl qjoypad qmenumodel-qml qpdf qt-at-spi qt4-linguist-tools
  qt4-qmake qtchooser qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-dee-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin qtdeclarative5-folderlistmodel-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0 qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-systeminfo-plugin qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content0.1
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin qtdeclarative5-window-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin quadrapassel rarian-compat retroarch
  rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugins sessioninstaller
  shotwell signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2
  signon-plugin-password signon-ui signond skype:i386 sni-qt sni-qt:i386
  software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
  soprano-daemon sound-juicer sp steam-launcher swell-foop synaptic syncwall
  synergy synfigstudio system-config-printer-gnome system-image-common
  system-image-dbus telepathy-haze telepathy-indicator texlive
  texlive-bibtex-extra texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils
  texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended
  texlive-luatex texlive-math-extra texlive-pictures texlive-pstricks
  thumbnailer-service thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support
  thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us tipa tomboy toshset totem
  totem-mozilla totem-plugins ttf-mscorefonts-installer
  ubuntu-download-manager ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-emulator
  ubuntu-emulator-runtime:i386 ubuntu-keyboard-data ubuntu-minimal
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  ubuntu-sso-client-qt ubuntu-standard ubuntu-system-service
  ubuntu-system-settings ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts
  ubuntu-vm-builder unattended-upgrades unity unity-control-center
  unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-friends unity-lens-music
  unity-lens-video unity-plugin-scopes unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-home
  unity-scope-mediascanner2 unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-scopes
  unity-scope-video-remote unity-tweak-tool unity-voice-service
  unity-webapps-qml unity-webapps-service unity8 unity8-private uno-libs3
  unrar update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier
  update-notifier-common upstart-app-launch upstart-app-launch-tools ure
  usermetricsservice variety virtualbox-5.0 vlc vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify
  vlc-plugin-pulse wally webapp-container webbrowser-app wine-staging
  wine-staging-amd64 wine-staging-i386:i386 winehq-staging xbmc xdiagnose
  xmind xorg xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl xscreensaver-gl-extra
  xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl xul-ext-unity xul-ext-websites-integration
  y-ppa-manager yad yelp zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zenity
```

just for it to update

```
The following NEW packages will be installed
  foomatic-filters gdebi-core jackd1 libjack0 libosp5 libostyle1c2
  linux-headers-3.13.0-77 linux-headers-3.13.0-77-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-77-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic openjade
  opensp packagekit packagekit-backend-aptcc packagekit-tools
  python3-packagekit streamer xawtv-plugins
The following packages have been kept back:
  gcc-4.9-base gcc-4.9-base:i386 libgcc1 libgcc1:i386 libx32gcc1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files cinnamon-bluetooth cinnamon-common cinnamon-session
  cinnamon-session-common cinnamon-settings-daemon
  cinnamon-settings-daemon-dev cpp-4.8 curl dolphin-emu-master
  firefox-locale-en fonts-opensymbol gcc-4.8-base gir1.2-gtk-2.0
  gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-nemo-3.0 gtk2-engines-pixbuf ibus
  ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm ifupdown
  initscripts kpartx lib32asan0 libasan0 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6
  libc6:i386 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 libc6-i386
  libc6-x32 libcurl3 libcurl3:i386 libcurl3-gnutls libgail-common libgail-dbg
  libgail18 libgcrypt11 libgcrypt11:i386 libgcrypt11-dev libgraphite2-3
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0-dbg
  libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgtk2.0-dev libgudev-1.0-0 libgudev-1.0-dev
  libhogweed2 libibus-1.0-5 libnemo-extension-dev libnemo-extension1
  libnettle4 libnss-winbind libnss3 libnss3:i386 libnss3-1d libnss3-1d:i386
  libnss3-dev libnss3-nssdb libpam-systemd libpam-winbind libpci3
  libreoffice-style-human libsmbclient libsystemd-daemon-dev
  libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-journal0 libsystemd-login-dev
  libsystemd-login0 libudev-dev libudev1 libudev1:i386 libwbclient0
  libx32asan0 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
  linux-libc-dev login muffin-common multiarch-support nemo-data ntpdate
  openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib openssh-client
  openssh-server openssh-sftp-server oxideqt-codecs-extra passwd pciutils
  python-ibus python-samba qemu-keymaps qemu-system-common rhythmbox-data
  samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  samba-vfs-modules smbclient ssh-askpass-gnome systemd-services sysv-rc
  sysvinit-utils udev winbind
```

So what can I do about it? Could there be security problems because of this?

Comment: You are upgrading your distribution you are going to have old packages that need to be removed so it can install new ones. As security works its more of a risk not to update the packages.

Comment: would it be worth upgrading?, and if I did how could I get all those packages back? would it be a security problem if I didn't dist-upgrade?

Comment: As described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/81594/166687) `dist-upgrade` smartly remove and updates outdated package(s) and outdates packages may brings security issues, so in my opinion, yes it's worth upgrading and it's always worth it