# Install xbacklight on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: mysql, xbacklight

I am trying to install xbacklight using

```
sudo apt-get install -y xbacklight
```

but getting error related to mysql.After running above command a new window pop up to set password for mysql.But after setting it shows following error in terminal.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xbacklight is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1534 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.30-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'
```

I have installed xbacklight in 14.04 Ubuntu.How should I do it in 15.04?

Comment: 15.04 is EOL, you should upgrade to a supported release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo mkdir /etc/mysql/conf.d
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then, I seriously suggest you update your software before doing anything else. Run one of the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or, recommended:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

[Click here if you don't know the difference.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)