# ubuntu says updates available after update and upgrade

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates

I have a 16.04 server on Digital Ocean that lists this when I ssh into it...

```
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

7 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.
```

I have run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` many times and it has not gone away.

After I run the upgrade I see this as the last line...

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I recommend using `apt` instead of `apt-get`, as it deals with such situations more intelligently (in particular, `sudo apt upgrade` would have upgraded those four packages).

Answer (score 24):

Since your using *ubuntu 16.04* the following should fix it:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

But if you prefer the *Ubuntu 14.04* way then:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If the two commands don't work you should talk to *digital ocean* about it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `dist-upgrade` command, which will perform upgrades that require changing dependencies, adding or removing new packages if necessary. This will handle a set of upgrades which may have been kept back by `apt-get upgrade`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

For more information see [What is "dist-upgrade" and why does it upgrade more then "upgrade" ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible your /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available file did not refresh after your last update.

If you want to set this manually:

```bsh
sudo su # Needed to acquire permissions.
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable >/var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
exit    # to get out of sudo
```

Note that /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available is set with 0600 for  permissions for the user & group 'root', which prevent you from simply sudo-ing the apt-check command to rewrite it.

Comment: It’s not the 600, but bash syntax. `apt-check` does’t need permission; the `>` does. Try replacing `>` with `| sudo tee` to verify.

Comment: This was the only working answer for me. Byobu was saying i had 1400+ upgradable packages, and apt list --installed indicated the same. Apt upgrade said 0 upgrades available.

Comment: `sudo /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable | sudo tee /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available && sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade && sudo apt -y autoremove`

Comment: I'd check this and update my answer, but I can't... I can update the answer, but I can't check that it works, as I lack a system with this problem at the moment.

Comment: I don't have a `/usr/lib/update-notifier` directory. `:-/`

Answer (score 2):

First of all the message

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

says that there are 4 packages not upgraded. I guess these are related to a newer kernel and can be upgraded with

```
apt-get full-upgrade
```

Besides that the message

```
7 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.
```

is not calculated every time you login so it might be outdated.

Comment: Is there a way I can force it to update? It used to clear everytime I updated the system and this time it has been stuck for over a week

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to this :(

Comment: `sudo apt full-apgrade` is the safest way to update what's available. If that doesn't help, one or more packages may be held back due to unmet dependendices. Normally that fixes itself in a few days.