# Questions About Kernel Upgrade and Computer Maintenance

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I just ran:

```
uname -r
```

and this came up:

```
4.4.0-53-generic
```

Then I did:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

the output was:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic
```

But when I run

```
uname -r
```

I still get

```
4.4.0-53-generic
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you rebooted after installing the new kernel? If not, there's your answer. The newer kernel will be used in the subsequent sessions only.

Answer (score 3):

After your first `uname -r` it listed **4.4.0-53** as the kernel version you last booted with.

When you did `sudo apt upgrade` it offered to update your disk with newer kernel `4.4.0-57` but you must select `Y` to upgrade it on disk. You did not say if you did this or not.

When you typed `uname -r` a second time it still shows **4.4.0-53** as the kernel you booted with because you haven't rebooted yet.

Anyways... Do the upgrade and select `Y` and then reboot to get the newest kernel booted into RAM and virtual directories `/proc`, `/sys`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get upgrade` is restricted to the case where packages are to be replaced by newer versions.

but in your case there are packages be additions, so you should use `apt-get dist-upgrade`. 
For example, 'linux-image-generic- package will update by 'linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic'.

See [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade) for more information.

Comment: Can you please explain what this command does?

Comment: @KazWolfe [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade) is a good answer to your question.

Comment: Can you please summarize that link into your answer. A simple [edit] would suffice. Be sure to link back to your source if appropriate

Comment: @KazWolfe Good suggestion, I added a description just now.

Comment: Now I do: `uname -r` and here is the result:
`4.4.0-57-generic`.
But Computer is still super slow. I do alt + tab a lot to switch between programs and it takes forever. and I am nor running anything heavy.
Any Idea?

Comment: @KenSandoval Well.. the kernel does not significantly affect system performance.
First of all, try to check the cpu usage of each process.

Comment: I've done that. and it is just internet browsing. for example, if I use chrome, I then, . I switch to firefox and is slow also then switch to chromium and is the same. . How to improve internet browsing performance then?. (ISP speed is fine and I connect with ethernet cable. I have 10 MB speed.