# 100% CPU due to "fwupd" process in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: process, cpu-load

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I did all available updates. 
When I turn on my laptop, sometimes I notice CPU working at 100% due to "fwupd" process and so I have to kill it manually to avoid getting battery discharged fast!
Is there a solution for this problem?

---

Ok I tested the solution I reported in my previous comment and it worked like a charm.

Comment: There is a launchpad site here that might help you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream-glib/+bug/1591868

Comment: Ok. It seems that removing and reinstalling gnome-software should fix it:

1) killall gnome-software
2) sudo killall fwupd
3) sudo apt-get update
4) sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
5) sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-software
6) sudo apt-get install gnome-software

Little question: Typing dist-upgrade should upgrade Ubuntu version to 16.10 ??

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't upgrade your ubuntu system (don't use ubuntu as often) but I can reassure you with this post here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it can be an apt-get cache problem so it's recommended to clean the cache :

1. sudo -ic
2. apt-get clean
3. cd /var/lib/apt
4. mv lists lists.old
5. mkdir -p lists/partial
6. apt-get clean
7. apt-get update

or it can be a permission problem

- sudo chown {user} /home/{user}/.cache/dconf

this solve the problem for me.