# Kubuntu Certain Programs Become Unoperable After Update?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, chromium, 17.04

After performing an `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` on Kubuntu 17.04, all of my browsers won't open when they are clicked. Upon further inspection in terminal, they all seem to have the same error message relating to `g_log_structured` Other than that, everything else seems fine. How can I fix this issue?

> `sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ firefox
>   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured
>       sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ chromium-browser
>       Using PPAPI flash.
>       --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --
>       ppapi-flash-version=
>       /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-
>       path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-
>       version=26.0.0.131 --enable-pinch: symbol lookup error: 
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: 
>       g_log_structured`

Edit 0: Upon further research, it appears that this may be a problem with `glib` Link to `g_log_structured`(https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Message-Logging.html#g-log-structured)

Comment: Please don't post terminal output as a screenshot. Post it is text.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd do a dist-upgrade on 17.04. You might find [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/81594/225694) informative.

Comment: You will  probably need to file a bug report.

Comment: @ElderGeek Shouldn't `dist-upgrade` be more useful since it removes obsolete packages?

Comment: @SarahSzabo That depends on whether you are using something that requires those obsolete packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the update had nothing to do with this particular issue. As pointed out in the question `glib` was causing the issue. I went to their Launchpad and downloaded the latest glib tar.xy for my version of Kubuntu and compiled and installed it. This solved the issue.