# Is apt dist-upgrade not necessary anymore

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, upgrade, update-manager

Before Ubuntu 18.04 was available, I was using Ubuntu 16.04. And I was using `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to do the update and upgrade stuff. 
With Ubuntu 18.04, I changed to to use `apt` instead of `apt-get`. What was weird for me is that `sudo apt dist-upgrade` has no effect anymore: I do the update and upgrade using `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgade`, but when I run `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, nothing happens contrary to when I was using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.
When I used `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` some packages were removed and others were installed. However when I run `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, nothing happened at all.. All what I get is:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And this happens every time since I started using `apt` instead of `apt-get`.
Is it something related to `apt` (i.e `sudo apt upgrade` replaces both `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`) or what is the issue exactly?

Comment: I'll be curious to see the full answer, but this seems to indicate that you are correct: https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## `apt-get upgrade` vs `apt upgrade` vs `apt full-upgrade`

`apt-get upgrade` only upgrades the apps, tools, and utilities. It does not install new Linux kernel of the OS.

`apt upgrade` upgrades the apps, tools, and utilities and installs new Linux kernel of the OS. However, it never removes old packages.

`apt full-upgrade` upgrades the apps, tools, and utilities and installs new Linux kernel of the OS. It also removes old packages if needed for the upgrade.

It looks to me `apt full-upgrade` does the same thing as `apt-get dist-upgrade`. That is to say the `full-upgrade` will check for and install a new kernel if available and removes old packages if the removal is necessary for the upgrade.

kernels are the fundamental part of the OS. For this reason the the old version of the kernel is never replaced by the new version when you run `apt upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade`. The new version of kernel is installed and the existing version is kept as is. The configuration in the grub is changed to boot from the new version by default during the upgrade process. If the new kernel does not work for some reason one can boot from the old kernel from the advanced grub menu.

Note, `apt full-upgrade` does not remove older versions of kernels as it installs the newest version. To remove these one must use `apt autoremove`.

## Why change the name from `dist-upgrade` to `full-upgrade`?

- If you use `apt-get` then you need to use `dist-upgrade`
- If you use `apt` then you need to use `full-upgrade`

I think the `dist-upgrade` was a bit confusing. For example, this does not upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04. It only upgrade the kernel, and other stuff, within Ubuntu 16.04.

I think `full-upgrade` is more intuitive than `dist-upgrade`.

See [What is "dist-upgrade" and why does it upgrade more than "upgrade"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade) for more details.

Full disclosure: I am just an user of Ubuntu I didn't make the decision to change it. These are my personal views.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1, but to be pedant, from the manpage of `apt` itself: `upgrade` _never removes existing packages_, while `full-upgrade` _will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole_. Also, `apt dist-upgrade` looks like to work ok on my systems (probably for backwards compatibility).

Comment: @MrShunz I know this is what the man page says. It is also mentioned in the other answer I will add as reference.

Comment: `apt upgrade` and `apt-get upgrade` handle the thing different, see hiroom2.com/2016/05/20/ubuntu-16-04-debian-8-apt-command/…

Comment: @mook765 Thanks! I will edit my answer based on your reference.

Comment: @user68186 Well, there was no other answer when I commented ;)

Comment: *"I think the dist-upgrade was a bit confusing."* I swear this is the understatement of the century regarding apt. Is there anything about apt that is *not* confusing?! Like what does the name "apt" or "aptitude" have to do with package management in the first place? Why are there 3 variations of apt? Why does apt-*get* *modify* my system? Why does "update" not update my system? Why does "upgrade" not upgrade my system? Why shouldn't it just update its internal cache before upgrading automatically like a sane OS? Why does purge uninstall a package instead of purging it from the cache? etc....

Comment: @user541686: good rant. I'm there.

Answer (score 16):

`dist-upgrade` has been superseded in Ubuntu by `full-upgrade`.

Older users of Ubuntu remember when `dist-upgrade` was indeed used regularly to install kernel packages. Kernel package names change with the version, making them ineligible for normal `upgrade`. `full-upgrade` was added to safely meet this need of the Ubuntu package flow.

The original purpose of `dist-upgrade` is to migrate between releases of Debian (roughly equivalent to Ubuntu's `do-release-upgrade`.) So there is a bit less protection from unanticipated consequences. Read the proposed changes carefully before agreeing.

Using `dist-upgrade` instead of `full-upgrade` probably won't hurt a healthy system. Millions of users over a decade have worked a lot of the bugs out of the apt workflow. However, `dist-upgrade` may have unexpected results on a system with held broken packages or other unresolved problems.

Comment: +1 for the original purpose of `dist-upgrade`.  One would have to fiddle with the `sources.list` to use it this way I guess.