# Why Ubuntu does not update all packages when I run sudo apt-get upgrade?

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu

I use Kubuntu and I use to update the system with the terminal running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

The system download and install packages. However, sometimes after updating the system still ask for updates and when I open the menu it shows pendant downloads at Discovery. Frequently the updates are kernel updates.

Why Ubuntu does not update all packages?

Comment: @user535733 Yes, mistranslated from a Romance (latin) language. The verb "actualizar" mean "update".

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes, I know. I was trying to spur the OP into correcting their question. The question is vague, and the OP needs to provide a clear example. For example, the OP might mistakenly think that the ssh login message is accurate. Or they might be looking at outdated information somewhere else. Or they might be confused by Phased Updates. Life is too short for us to guess and speculate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo apt update` means to update the repository information, not to download anything. Basically a list of available packages and their versions will be downloaded and stored.

Then you might "update and install" existing code by executing:

```
sudo apt upgrade.
```

Still some packages may be held back. (e.g Kernel). To get all the new stuff you can issue

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

As user535733 mentioned in the comments there is a 3rd possibility to upgrade:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112555/is-apt-dist-upgrade-not-necessary-anymore/1112567#1112567) for a full explanation of the two upgrade commands

Comment: In Debian, it's `dist-upgrade`. For Ubuntu, the apt developers created `full-upgrade`. Minor differences.

Comment: Well thank you. I didn't know. `dist-upgrade` still works though

Comment: And `full-upgrade` works in Debian. The Apt developers for Debian and Ubuntu don't want to be troubled to endlessly maintain two codebases...so they don't. It's up to the users to read the documentation (including AskUbuntu) and use the correct command for their distro.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As far as I understand, full-upgrade also enables you to upgrade to the next version - something I 've done once.. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: neither `dist-upgrade` nor `full-upgrade` should be used to upgrade to the next version on Ubuntu - `do-release-upgrade` is the command for that. Also there really aren't any meaningful differences between `dist-upgrade` and `full-upgrade` afaik - the latter was created to have a less confusing name.

Comment: Is there any difference between `apt`and `apt-get`?

Comment: @Universal_learner apt is just a new *interface* for `apt-get` and `apt-cache`. Its output has a slightly different format to that of the older commands, but it's using the same code as those commands so it has exactly the same capabilities and options (however the `apt` man page is incomplete - some options can only be found in the `apt-get` and `apt-cache` man pages) and gives the same results.

Comment: @Zanna thank you, I wondered abut the difference. Now I will run just apt