ubuntu / Deb / Update vs upgrade vs dist update
Im seeing lots of options of update vs upgrade and Dist update... ect.
so i would like to know what is what and what order, and what is needed and not needed and so on.
iv used....
sudo apt update = what?
sudo apt upgrade = what?
sudo apt-get update = what?
sudo apt-get upgrade = what?
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade / or sudo apt dist-upgrade = what? or what is the proper way.
sudo apt full-upgrade or sudo apt-get full-upgrade = what? or what is the proper way.
so what is the proper way... to get all updates / all packages / all OS updates. and so on, just so many options.
i know u have to do update 1st, and upgrade 2.  / then what 3rd. would be dist-upgrade ??? / just so comfused, and what other commands do i need to use.
Im so sorry about being newbe. im trying to learn linux. LOL.

First you should take a look at the related man pages (man apt, man apt-get).

Previously there was only apt-get. Later it was renamed (sort of) to the shorter version apt, and the apt-get remains there for backward compatibility. apt update (or apt-get update) only updates the information about available software and their upgrades, but do not upgrade/update the software themselves. That is done via upgrade/full-upgrade/dist-upgrade (which are almost the same, their differences are written in https://askubuntu.com/a/1112567/124466)

Thanks. so i think i got it.  sudo apt-get = older ver. like v16 / and sudo apt is new OS like v18+.

If apt would do everything apt-get did; the apt-get tool would have been deprecated or retired; alas there are options/capabilities that apt-get can do that apt cannot.. which is why both tools still exist..  The newer apt does the most-often used features of apt-get better & easier it's believed; but there are times when apt-get is still required.. thus why both still exist today.   FYI:  Most average users will never need apt-get, but maintainers of 100s/1000s of machines will need it a few times per year..

apt is not recommended for use in scripts, see this question
