# New package vs new version?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel, updates

In the question [What is “dist-upgrade” and why does it upgrade more than “upgrade”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade) the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/81594/455894) explains that `linux-headers-3.0.0-13` is a new package replacing `linux-headers-3.0.0-12`.

How is it a new package and not simply a new version, and how to know (recognize) the difference?

Further, why is `linux-headers-3.0.0-13` listed in the output of the command `sudo apt-get upgrade` if it is a new package and not a new version of an already installed package?

The answer hints at the argument that it is because `linux-headers-3.0.0-12` and `linux-headers-3.0.0-13` are *connected to* the same virtual package ("`linux-headers` is a virtual package that is provided by both `linux-headers-3.0.0-12` and `linux-headers-3.0.0-13`"). Is it for this reason that `linux-headers-3.0.0-13` is listed? And if so, why don't we see other packages provided by other virtual packages suggested as upgrades?

EDIT:

Although the example above concerns kernel packages, my question is not kernel-oriented but more general; or is it of kernel-only relevance?

Comment: dist-upgrade: in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages, it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason of having kernel meta-packages like `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` pointing to real kernel packages is to allow having more than one instance of a kernel.

You can have `linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic` and `linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic` installed at the same time.

When you upgrade meta `linux-headers-generic`, it pulls the latest real package as a dependency. If we had these kernel packages as one with different versions, it would be always replaced.

`apt-get upgrade` doesn't install new packages

```
 upgrade
           upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
           currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
           /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently installed with new
           versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no
           circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
           not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of
           currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without
           changing the install status of another package will be left at
           their current version. An update must be performed first so that
           apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available.
```

That's why it doesn't upgrade meta packages that are dependent on new packages.

It is not kernel related. There are some other examples.

Comment: Oh. So the key-word here is "dependency": it is because the new _version_ of the virtual package `linux-header-generic` includes new _dependencies_ that `linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic` is listed but not fetched due to the rules of the `apt-get upgrade` command. And so it is not a kernel-specific scenario but it could occur with other non-kernel packages when a new package version has new.  dependencies. Is that correct?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Thank you @Pilot6. I also note that the other key-word here is "meta-package" instead of "virtual package" - other packages linked to a virtual package would actually not be considered by apt-get, right?

Comment: It is very simple. `apt-get upgrade` doesn't install NEW packages.

Comment: Yes, I know. I understand now that the confusion came from the term "virtual package" used in the answer I referred to. Thank you.

Comment: meta and virtual look same to me. These packages don't contain anything but links to other ones.

Comment: From what I understand, virtual packages are more function-oriented: a virtual package is more like a flag to a package to indicate that it provides a generic function which other packages might depend on (see the related Debian GNU/Linux FAQ [paragraph about virtual packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-virtual))

Comment: In short: meta-packages include (depend on) other packages, and packages can "contain" virtual packages, but not the reverse.

Answer (score 4):

> How is it a new package and not simply a new version, and how to know (recognize) the difference?

Different packages have different names. Different versions of the same package have the same package name and different version numbers. You can see your installed packages and their version numbers with, *e.g.*, `apt list --installed`:

```
firas@itsuki ~ % apt list --installed | grep linux-image
linux-image-4.18.0-14-generic/cosmic-updates,cosmic-security,now 4.18.0-14.15 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic/cosmic-updates,cosmic-security,now 4.18.0-15.16 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-generic/cosmic-updates,cosmic-security,now 4.18.0.15.16 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Here I have three installed packages whose names contain `linux-image`: `linux-image-4.18.0-14-generic` version `4.18.0-14.15`, `linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic` version `4.18.0-15.16`, and `linux-image-generic` version `4.18.0.15.16`. In particular, `linux-image-4.18.0-14-generic` and `linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic` are different names, so they are different packages. Don't be fooled by how similar the names are, the point is that they are not the same. They might as well be named `foo` and `bar`.

Also, in the file names of `.deb` packages, the package name and version number are typically separated by underscores:

```
firas@itsuki ~ % ls /home/apt/archives/linux-image-*
/home/apt/archives/linux-image-4.18.0-14-generic_4.18.0-14.15_amd64.deb
/home/apt/archives/linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic_4.18.0-15.16_amd64.deb
/home/apt/archives/linux-image-generic_4.18.0.15.16_amd64.deb
```

Comment: That's what I planned to add, but was too lazy. A good one.

Comment: Great complement to the answer of Pilot6. Thank you!