# apt update shows available packages, but full-upgrade shows none upgraded

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I just noticed this while updating:

```
hiigaran@hiigaran:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for hiigaran: 
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease         
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                              
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5 kB]                                                                         
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases/ubuntu disco InRelease                              
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                 
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]                                   
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-proposed InRelease [255 kB]             
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu disco InRelease    
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Fetched 539 kB in 2s (262 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
hiigaran@hiigaran:~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
linux-image-generic/disco-proposed 5.0.0.22.23 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.0.21.22]
N: There are 3 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
hiigaran@hiigaran:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
hiigaran@hiigaran:~$
```

Running `sudo apt update` shows that there is a package available, which in this case is the 5.0.0.22.23 package. However, upon running `sudo apt full-upgrade`, it shows no packages will be upgraded.

I'm not particularly fussed about getting this package. Just curious as to why this happened, as I've never experienced it before.

Comment: Packages in `-proposed` are not official releases, so I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: `apt` seems pretty on-topic to me, and Ubuntu's software updater provides the option of enabling proposed packages. Since I'm asking about why `apt` did something, and not how to install a package that is listed as proposed, I fail to see how this is off-topic.

Comment: @mchid `-proposed` is equivalent to a development release; it contains packages which are in various stages of development, and may even be completely broken, as is the case here. We don't want to support that.

Comment: @mchid The question is about the package being broken; specifically, about why it cannot be installed.

Comment: @fkraiem: Unless there's another variant of broken packages, I should get the relevant message after running my `apt` commands. As my terminal output shows, this is not the case, so my question is not about that, or for support installing this package. I just want to understand the outputs `apt` has given me, and why, without any additional information, it chooses not to install a supposedly available package. Well within the realms of what's considered on-topic, according to `/help/dont-ask` and `/help/on-topic`.

Comment: Meta question: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18740/proposed-should-be-off-topic-even-for-supported-releases

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt full-upgrade` dont does the same thing as `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
`sudo apt list --upgradable -a` shows a proposed update because you have selected pre-released updates in the Software Properties App.
If you want to install the update, simply run this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

If you dont want to install the pre-released packages go with Sotware Properties App to uncheck a box:

[image]

Get more information about apt upgrade options:

Read [apt-get man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get.8)

***apt-get upgrade*** actually installs newer versions of the packages you have. After updating the lists, the package manager knows about available updates for the software you have installed. This is why you first want to update.
**apt-get dist-upgrade**, in addition to performing the function of apt-get upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages and will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary. Thus, the apt-get dist-upgrade command may actually remove some packages in rare but necessary instances.
**apt full-upgrade**
full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but may also remove
installed packages if that is required in order to resolve a
package conflict.

Also on this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/81594/77093

Comment: -1 `dist-upgrade` will not install the update. The package is broken and cannot be installed.

Comment: @fkraiem I dont think so. Please show where you see it is broken and post an answer.

Comment: @fkraiem if `apt dist-upgrade` does not install the package you should add this information with the relevant output to the question. --- I have the same problem with "python3-gdbm/bionic 3.6.9-1~18.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.6.8-1~18.04]" from this PPA http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa/ubuntu

Comment: @pabouk I am not the question asker.