# Ubuntu 18.04 on new Dell 3584 keeps freezing

Tags: 18.04, dell, freeze

yesterday I bought Dell 3584 which came with Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled. When I started the system it froze at some point, after that I installed the updates, switched to KDE but it still keeps freezing. I've searched many topics but not sure what to do.

Under software and updates I have one unknown.unknown driver, could this be the problem?

[image: Screenshot of my additional drivers tab]

If this is Ubuntu only issue, will switching to some other distro help? I'm thinking Arch or openSUSE.

Here is output of *lspci -v:*

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5921 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 08d1
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 132
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
        Memory at d1420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
        Memory at d1410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
        Memory at d1437000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
        Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at d1436000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
        Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
        Memory at d1435000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
        Memory at d1430000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Memory at d1434000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
        I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
        I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
        Memory at d1433000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
        Memory behind bridge: d1300000-d13fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
        Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
        Capabilities: [220] #19
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: d1000000-d11fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [100] #00
        Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
        Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
        Capabilities: [220] #19
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: d1200000-d12fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
        Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
        Capabilities: [220] #19
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 08d1
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP PMC
        Flags: fast devsel
        Memory at d142c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 135
        Memory at d1428000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at d1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at d1432000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
        Memory at d1304000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at d1300000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-36-4c-e0-00
        Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
        Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134
        Memory at d1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
        Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
        Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Device 1987:5008 (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
        Subsystem: Device 1987:5008
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
        Memory at d1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [80] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=9 Masked-
        Capabilities: [e0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [f8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1556 Rev=1 Len=008 <?>
        Capabilities: [108] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [110] L1 PM Substates
        Capabilities: [128] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [300] #19
        Kernel driver in use: nvme
```

Comment: On your side I would upgrade it to 19.10, change kernel, install new graphics driver: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers && apt update && apt dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but after running this command, new graphics repo will be added, repository content will be refreshed and then the distribution will be upgraded. So I still have to change kernel (I'm assuming through GRUB) and install graphics drivers somehow?

Comment: You could see the answer here about dist-upgrade: https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I generally recommend one to stay with LTS - do not upgrade to non-LTS version because if you want to keep getting updates, you will have to upgrade your non-LTS version again (and again), and those non-LTS upgrades are very fragile and unreliable. In comparison, upgrading from LTS to LTS is much more robust.

Keep your LTS, if you need newer kernels, install the hwe stack, see instructions from here

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_-_Bionic_Beaver

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, everything I've tried didn't work... 
I ended up switching to openSUSE, it works without any problems, no more freezing.