# Why security updates not included in apt-get repository?

Tags: software-center, security, update-manager, software-sources

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

When I use:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

in the terminal, my software repository is updated, and the softwares are upgraded by some download.
However, when I go to "Software Updater", there are some security updates present, namely:

Generic Linux kernel header, Generic Linux kernel image, etc. (almost worth ~75 MB).

I got confused because these security updates were not downloaded and installed when I ran:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Why is it so?

Should they be downloaded?

Should I also enable (tick) Canonical Partners repository in Software & Updates > Other Software to get security updates?

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` has certain limits it works within, if you want to install all upgrades use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.  The `man apt-get` will tell you "*dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages...*"  (read it yourself for all the details)

Comment: Actually I think https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade is better, sorry I tagged the wrong one...

Comment: @guiverc Should I also enable (tick) Canonical Partners repository in Software & Updates > Other Software to get security updates?

Comment: Refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu (see *Adding Extra Repositories* for the details) for Canonical Parters; and no, in most cases, it won't provide extra security updates as provide alternate software - not upgraded packages to software you already have.  (*It maybe possible that if you hardware came pre-installed with Ubuntu, that may be necessary, but if you downloaded & installed it yourself I can't see that as necessary*)