# Upgrade 20.04 to 20.10 fails, missing updates

Tags: upgrade, 20.10

When trying to upgrade 20.04 to 20.10 using update-manager button Upgrade, I get a message that I must first install all updates. I did sudo apt update + upgrade and I installed all updates suggested by update manager. Now I get no message in the terminal, but nothing happens when I click the button Upgrade or use the command sudo apt -y update && apt -y dist-upgrade.
Fyi: I have a triple boot system with Windows 10/Ubuntu LTS 20.04.1 and Ubuntu development version (currently 20.04.1) on tree different partitions (2 hard disks).

Comment: Try running `update-manager -p` in the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You're on an LTS (long time support) version. There is some safety built in the system that you don't inadvertently upgrade to a non-LTS version.

To overrule this, just for this upgrade, do:

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

and change `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal`.

Then do `sudo do-release-upgrade` and your upgrade should proceed normally.

Comment: Hello Jos. I already had promtpt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades. The command sudo do-release-upgrade gives me the same output in the terminal: Gelieve eerst alle beschikbare updates voor uw versie te installeren alvorens u begint met de upgrade. Translation: please install all available updates for your version before starting the upgrade. What should I do now? I have downloaded the 20.10 iso, but I prefer to not use that.

Comment: You may need to do `sudo apt dist-upgrade` first. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade).

Comment: That did not work either. Same message about first updating lts version. I did sudo apt-get update and upgrade once again before do-release-upgrade.

Comment: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade does not work either. Message: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to be removed and 0 not upgraded

Comment: Strange. I can't think of anything else to try at this point. Perhaps `sudo apt clean` and reboot?

Comment: `sudo apt dist-upgrade` thanks jobs !

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

I had two packages (related to tor) failing install due to an unmet dependancy. (found using `sudo apt list --upgradable`)

So I removed tor and did the upgrade:

```
sudo apt remove tor

sudo do-release-upgrade
```

And then proceeded with the install.

I would reinstall tor after the upgrade.

The lack of error messages was frustrating.

I'm sure it's logged somewhere.