# Docker restarted by dist-upgrade despite being pinned and staying the same version?

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, updates, docker

Having read this answer on Ask Ubuntu: [What is “dist-upgrade” and why does it upgrade more than “upgrade”?](https://askubuntu.com/a/81594/917609)

I'm still not sure what happened here in my situation.

On a local server, Ubuntu 18.04, I have docker pinned to an older version.

The file is located here: `/etc/apt/preferences.d/docker-ce.pref`

And the contents are:

```
Explanation: Pin added by Ansible role "nickjj.docker"
Package: docker-ce
Pin: version 19.03.5-ce*
Pin-Priority: 600
```

Someone performed `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` on this server, according to the `auth.log` file.

Docker didn't get upgraded, but was clearly restarted. I learned this because the service file in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` was reset to the default.

After this, I learned you shouldn't do edits there, but do `sudo systemctl edit docker.service`.

But that's another story. Point is: I did make those edits in the past and then they were gone. The service had either been upgraded or restarted, and it turned out it wasn't upgraded.

I don't get why it restarted. It's pinned, so it shouldn't come up during upgrades.

That being said, `dist-upgrade` details some sort of conflict resolution between dependencies.

Could it be that `dist-upgrade` forced a restart of the service?

No other commands were found in `auth.log`, it's really weird.

Comment: Try pin priority 1001

Comment: Yes, `dist-upgrade` will restart services where required. Just because Docker didn’t receive any updates doesn’t mean that a dependency didn’t 

Comment: @matigo Gosh darnit. Well, if you turn that into a fully fledged answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: You can probably also verify whether the docker version changed (sounds like there's some uncertainty) by checking /var/log/apt/history.log.