# I don't understand why I can't update/grade from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: upgrade

I am wanting to update from Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04.

When I first tried I was getting an error:

```
W: GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF622 Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016) <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF622 Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016) <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy-proposed Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF622 Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016) <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>
```

Which seems that the key  has expired.  (Shrug)

I *fixed* it by doing this:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F2EDC64DC5AEE1F6B9C621F0C8CAB6595FDFF622

sudo apt-get update
```

But it only got rid of that part.

When I try to `sudo dist-upgrade` this happens:

```
 sudo apt dist-upgrade 
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  dh-python
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

So I don't understand why it isn't updating to 21.04

Please, someone.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Again I am not understanding the mechanics of posting questions and follow up posts on/in this forum.   I **DID** click the Up arrow as you said.  We had maybe better leave things as they are now or we will only be further making things confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the correct command.

The command you should run is `sudo do-release-upgrade` .

`apt dist-upgrade` is something entirely different.

See: [What is "dist-upgrade" and why does it upgrade more than "upgrade"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)

Comment: Ok, very much thanks.
But when I do that I am told to update the distro first.   I do the `sudo apt update` and it says 1 can be upgradable.   When I try to upgrade it:  nothing happens, and so I can't get it working.

Comment: Ah!    This is the link [link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-21-04) and I got stuck at the `dist-upgrade` part and looked further down and the `do-dist-upgrade` command is there.
I just didn't get to that part because of the error.

Comment: Is `dh-python` still the package that is being held back?  Can you try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dh-python`?  You also need to make sure that all PPAs and non-official sources are removed.