# Upgrade to 22.04.1 not possible

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04, lts, do-release-upgrade

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 template, which is used to create two Virtual Machines.

After creating the VMs I ran `apt update && apt upgrade -y` on both, now I've got one VM with version "22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)" and one "22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)". Even with `do-release-upgrade` I can not upgrade it so the versions are equal.

This is bad since one VM is for production and the other for development, and i want to keep the OS as close as possible.

Did the "phased release" approach of Ubuntu lead to this behaviour? And how to get both VMs to version "22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)". (I could update the template, i know)

Comment: I think the most safe solution would be to update the template. I'm not familiar with the "inner workings" of the internal point release updater. My servers have always updated themselves to the next point release. Did you try and run `sudo apt full-upgrade`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe running `sudo apt upgrade` might not be enough to ensure a full upgrade to next point release. You should instead run a `full-upgrade`:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

This will update the kernel packages etc., and also upgrade to the next point release. This was called `dist-upgrade` with `apt-get`, but `full-upgrade` provides the same functionality with `apt`.

Also, see this [related answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade).

Comment: Running `sudo apt full-upgrade` does update additional packages (when run after apt upgrade), but only the kernel. No upgrade to the point release

Comment: Well, it does work after all.
We register new VMs in Red Hat Satellite and i guess the VM which updated to the point release was using old Repositories and not yet our custom mirror.

Updating the template with full-upgrade gets it to this exact point release (currently!) so this is the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to hear.